# Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?

Tags: word-choice, possessives, personal-pronouns, singular-they, gender-neutral

Is there a pronoun I can use as a gender-neutral pronoun when referring back to a singular noun phrase?

> Each student should save **his** questions until the end.
> Each student should save **her** questions until the end.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100352/discussion-on-question-by-nulldevice-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Comment: @StuW  "We could use an answer from the transgender community. **There are none amongst the first 23 answers.**" How could you possibly know that?

Comment: I read the 23 answers. But it is possible one of the answers is "accepted" nomenclature with the transgender community. I just don't think so, and either way, a transgendered individual would be best qualified to answer the question (i believe).

Comment: By intuition, *each student should save **their** questions until the end* -- sounds appropriate in conversations.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

[Singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) enjoys a long history of usage in English and can be used here: "Each student should save their questions until the end."

However, “singular *they*” also enjoys a long history of criticism. If you are anxious about being criticized (for what is in fact a perfectly grammatical construction) I would advise rewording to avoid having to use a gender-neutral singular third-person pronoun.

Some rewording strategies that can be employed:

- Use a plural noun: *Students should save their questions until the end.*
- Use the formal *one*: *One should save one's questions until the end.*
- Use *his or her*: *Each student should save his or her questions until the end*

---

#### OED References for “singular” *they*

Here for the benefit of those who lack access to its paywalled source are the full and complete operative senses from the *Oxford English Dictionary*. [Per the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700) the pronoun ***they*** has these specific subsenses for the various scenarios under discussion here:

> 2. In anaphoric reference to a singular noun or pronoun.
>
>    <sup>Use of *they* to refer to a singular antecedent has sometimes been considered erroneous.</sup>
>
> > <sub>[**Dennis Baron • *A brief history of singular ‘they’***](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/)</sub>
> >
> > <sub>…But that’s nothing new. The Oxford English Dictionary traces singular *they* back to 1375, where it appears in the medieval romance William and the Werewolf. Except for the old-style language of that poem, its use of singular *they* to refer to an unnamed person seems very modern. Here’s the Middle English version: ‘Hastely hiȝed eche  … þei neyȝþed so neiȝh… þere william & his worþi lef were liand i-fere.’ In modern English, that’s: ‘Each man hurried… till they drew near… where William and his darling were lying together.’…</sub>
> >
> > <sup>[4 September 2018]</sup>

> - **2a.** With an antecedent that is grammatically singular, but refers collectively to the members of a group, or has universal reference (e.g. *each person, everyone, nobody*).
>
>   <sup>Sometimes, but not always, used to avoid having to specify the gender(s) of the individual(s) being referred to; cf. sense [A. 2b.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700#eid1288185420)</sup>
>
>   [[citations ranging from **1350–2014** omitted]]

> - **2b.**  With an antecedent referring to an individual generically or indefinitely (e.g. *someone, a person, the student*), used esp. so as to make a general reference to such an individual without specifying gender. Cf. [**ʜᴇ** *pron*. 2b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84893#eid302969944).
>
>   <sup>In the 21st century, other *th–* pronouns (and the possessive adjective *their*) are sometimes used to refer to a named individual, so as to avoid revealing or making an assumption about that person’s gender; cf. sense [A. 2c](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700#eid1288185480), and quots. [2008 at **ᴛʜᴇɪʀ** *adj*. 2b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200291#eid1033522681), [2009 at **ᴛʜᴇᴍ** *pron*. 4b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200315#eid1033548561), [2009 at **ᴛʜᴇᴍꜱᴇʟꜰ** *pron*. 2b.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/334443#eid1033656331)</sup>
>
>   [[citations ranging from **1450–2010** omitted]]

> - **2c.** Used with reference to a person whose sense of personal identity does not correspond to conventional sex and gender distinctions, and who has typically asked to be referred to as *they* (rather than as *he* or *she*).
>
>   [[citations ranging from **2009–2019** omitted]]

> > > <sup><sub>Copyright © 2019 Oxford University Press. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

[Retrieved](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700) 2019-10-25 23:46:13 UTC, and shown here under the [Fair Use Exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Comment: Each and every are lovely words, and the only way to get people to understand them properly is to keep them in use! Perhaps we should teach logic to everyone from a young age - then there'll be no trouble.

Comment: Using the plural noun is what I normally do to not use a gender pronoun. Are there cases where, in example, "students should save their questions until the end" is interpreted differently from "each student should save his/her questions until the end"?

Comment: I'm a big supporter of singular they.  We managed to get singular you to replace thou - and even the once-controversial "yourself" is accepted as correct English.  I still find "themself" hard to accept as correct, but I think it's the only sensible solution.  "Zie" just looks like taking political-correctness to the ludicrous level, with the rare exception of when you are dealing with a known person of a determinate gender that is neither male nor female.

Comment: @Richard: Not sure about other countries, but here in Ireland singular they is very common. For the most part, instead of "themself" we tend to use "themselves". As in, instead of "He/she should think for himself/herself", it would be "They should think for themselves".

Comment: "Questions should be kept to the end" avoids the indeterminate pronoun problem. I think this sort of solution is often less awkward than the "singular they" construction.

Comment: "Singular 'they' enjoys a long history" indeed! It was good enough for King James, it's good enough for me: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003485.html

Comment: I long ago learned to stop worrying and love the singular `they`.

Comment: [Everybody Has their own opinion about the singular _they._](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf)

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I think a WTF face would be the best expression for *singular they*.

Comment: @Stan it's no different than singular *you*.

Comment: @nohat So, why we can see *singular you* everywhere but there have to be criticism for *singular they*? In grammar they may work the same, though.

Comment: Because some people just have to have something to pick on, that's all. Ignore them.

Comment: The argument for singular they is much stronger when dealing with indefinite syntactically singular prounouns like "everyone", or "anyone" etc. "Every student" would much more reasonably be paired with "they", or even better "everyone" (that you are referring to the students is clear from context). And even better: simply "students".

Comment: "However, 'singular they' also enjoys a long history of criticism". Well, only since the mid-18th as a recommendation and the late-18th as an attempt at an outright ban. A long enough history, to be sure, but short compared to the entire history of Modern English and much of Middle English in which writers like Chaucer, Shakespeare, the KJV translators, Wilde, Auden, Shaw and Orwell all used it without qualm.

Comment: "*However, “singular they” also enjoys a long history of criticism. If you are anxious about being criticized (for what is in fact a perfectly grammatical construction) I would advise rewording to avoid having to use a gender-neutral singular third-person pronoun*."

On discussing the subject, it is important to distinguish between a non-specific indefinite person and a specific definite person, though many people don't seem to realize this.
Please read my answer(there are two answers of mine. I mean the new one) for the detail.

Comment: @nohat It's true that "you" can be either singular or plural. But I think this is a defect in English. It often creates unintentional ambiguities. The fact that our language is screwed up in one place isn't a good reason to screw it up in other places.

Comment: @Jay ambiguity in a language is one of its core sources of expressive richness, not a measure of its defectiveness.

Comment: "his or her" is still bad, I'd still avoid it.

Comment: "They" is the only correct pronoun for some LGBTQIA+ people. +1.

Comment: The prevailing argument against a singular "they" isn't usually backed up by actual grammatical "facts", as such, rather antagonism towards the LGBTQIA+ community. "You" can be used in both the singular and plural in the English language, and only from context can a definitive answer be found, so why is "they" not given the same treatment? It's unfortunate.

Comment: From the perspective of someone fully fluent in English, but for whom it is not my native language, I find "singular they" is going to be a singularly difficult concept for people who are less proficient in English.  That might not matter if your audience is only native speakers, but it should be a big red flag in many cases, including business and technical communication, where the audience may not be fully proficient and may not be familiar with current trends in certain English speaking countries.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Do... do you often deal with centuries old vampires or something?

Answer (score 133):

To round out the answers here, **one** is a very proper way to encompass both male and female antecedents.

> To boldly go where no one has gone before

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100340/discussion-on-answer-by-caleb-thompson-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singula).

Answer (score 59):

For what it's worth, in academic writing I exclusively use the singular third person masculine "he", recognized by many as gender-neutral. Many other languages do this without concern: German and Spanish come to mind.

In everyday speech I will unconsciously use singular "they". In my book, this has unquestionably drifted into very common use in all but the most formal situations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100339/discussion-on-answer-by-charlie-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-prono).

Comment: "Many other languages do this without concern: German" I'd say, this statement is not true anymore. Gender neutral wording is getting more and more usual in German.

Comment: I'd say the concern is indeed extra-linguistic from the start.

Answer (score 47):

It is common to write, "Each student should save **his or her** questions until the end" or to vary *his* and *her* throughout your text. In speech you will often hear native speakers say, "Each student should save **their** questions until the end."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100341/discussion-on-answer-by-edward-tanguay-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singula).

Answer (score 42):

There have been a number of efforts to create new pronouns that would be gender neutral. Some other posters here have given examples. But none of these have really caught on. I'll hazard the prediction that none will. It's difficult enough to invent a new word and get people to use it. To invent a new word in a context where people are routinely using an existing word is very difficult. Pronouns are more difficult still as they are used ALL THE TIME. That is, if you invent a new word for, say, a type of fish, someone writing about fish could mention the new word, define it for those unfamiliar with it, and then use it a few times in the following discussion. Someone expecting to learn something new about fish wouldn't be too jarred to learn a new word along with some new facts. But pronouns are used all the time in many contexts -- heck, it almost EVERY context. And they are used over and over. You don't use a word like "it" or "she" just two or three times in a page of text -- you use it dozens of times, often multiple times within one sentence. Using a new pronoun really stands out and is jarring and distracting.

So in real life, the solutions offerred to this problem are:

1. Stick with the traditional use of "he/him/his" as the generic pronouns. If we are talking about a specific person who is female, of course use "she". If we are talking about a person who is a member of a class which is always or usually female -- like mothers or nurses -- use "she". Otherwise use "he". Disadvantages: May sometimes be misleading, implying that a person must be a male when this is not the case. Advantages: Easy to use. Consistent with traditional use of the language. Offends feminists. (Well, some consider that to be a disadvantage.)
2. Use "they" as a singular pronoun. Disadvantages: Often considered to be grammatically incorrect because of improper agreement with antecedent. Can be misleading as to whether one person or many is intended. Advantages: Is widely enough used that it is generally understood.
3. Use pronouns of both genders together, like "he or she" or "him/her". Disadvantages: Quickly becomes awkward, e.g., "After he or she fills in his or her information on the form, he or she should specify whether he or she wants the form returned to him or her ..." In some cases creates ambiguity about whether one or two people are involved, e.g. "Give this to him or her" -- does that mean that the person I give it to may be of either sex, or that there are two people and I must give it to one or the other? Advantages: Clearly indicates that the person can be of either sex. No grammatical inconsistency.
4. Alternate use of genders, either within a "short space" or a "long space". When done within a very short space this can be confusing, like "He should do A and then she should do B." Clearly sounds like two people are involved. But if, say, you are giving two examples of jobs that must be performed, you could use "he" to refer to the person in the first example and "she" in the second. Disadvantages: Requires an extra effort during composition to continually switch genders, possibly re-writing all the pronouns in a paragraph if you move things around in editing. May still be distracting depending on context. Advantages: Avoids all grammar problems while still maintaining a form of gender neutrality.
5. Reword sentences to always use a plural. For example, instead of saying, "Each student should bring his book", say, "The students should bring their books", etc. Disadvantages: May lead to implicit changes in meaning, e.g. from identifying an individual responsibility to a collective responsibility. In some cases it may be impossible without changing the meaning, like try to reword, "He was the only person who volunteered" to use the plural without changing the meaning. Advantages: No problems with grammatical correctness.

Personally I generally use #1 for formal writing (because it retains strict grammatical correctness), and #2 for informal writing and speech.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100343/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun).

Answer (score 32):

I remember reading somewhere that it was recommended to use the opposite of what most people stereotype the profession as. So, for example, when talking about a chiropractor, you would use "her", and when talking about a secretary, you would use "his".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100342/discussion-on-answer-by-senseful-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pron).

Answer (score 29):

*Her* is not recommended or standard. *His* is standard, though the recommended way would be to change "**Each student** should.." to "**The students** should...".

"**Students** should..." is more abstract, and refers to students in general, rather than a specific group of students.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100351/discussion-on-answer-by-arlen-beiler-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Answer (score 24):

It's not my area of expertise, I'm not using it, and just learned about its existence today, so just for reference from Wikipedia's [Spivak pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun):

> The **Spivak pronouns** are a proposed set of gender-neutral pronouns in English devised by Michael Spivak. They are not in widespread use, but have been employed in gender-neutral language by some people who dislike the more common alternatives "he/she" or singular they.
>
> The (new) Spivak pronouns are formed from the pronoun "they" by dropping the "th".
>
> There are two variants of the Spivak pronouns in use, as shown in the declension table below.
>
> [image: Spivak]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100344/discussion-on-answer-by-arjan-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun).

Answer (score 24):

Historical note (USA).  When I started learning English, I was taught unequivocally that he/him/his was to be used when referring to a singular person of unknown gender (e.g. a hypothetical person). Then while I was still in school there was a long, concerted effort by feminists to change this usage as they saw it as making females feel like second class people.  As an example, they would ask, how do you fill in the blank in this sentence:

> If a child wants to become a doctor, (blank) should be encouraged.

If you fill in the blank with *he* (as I was taught and had been the rule for a very long time), the argument goes, you are sending a message to girls that they should not be encouraged to become doctors.  I found it very irritating because the rules I had just learned were being challenged.  Even worse, there was no agreed upon new rule and I was still in that childhood phase of wanting strict rules about whatever I was learning.  Many alternatives were proposed, and for more than a decade writers struggled with the issue, but by now the most widely accepted solution is to use the singular *they*.  *If a child wants to become a doctor, they should be encouraged*. I have come to fully embrace it.

Edit: I have been enlightened through this Q&A as to much earlier examples of this same kind of argument, such as:

> It would be interesting if each of the leading poets would tell us what he considers his best work.
>
> --"Famed grammarian and linguist" Otto Jespersen, *Progress in Language: With Special Reference to English*, 1894

This is the first I've heard of such arguments despite having had **many** arguments over *he* versus *they* in the 1970's and 1980's. I will simply point out that while it does show that the argument is quite old, it also shows that the controversy is quite old.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100346/discussion-on-answer-by-old-pro-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-prono).

Answer (score 22):

The "singular they" sounds totally wrong to my ear.  But I am conscious of the implicit gender bias our language can have at times.  So, I prefer to choose "his" or "her" either at random, or with a bias against the stereotype: use "his" when most people would assume you're talking about a woman; use "her" when most would assume a man.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100345/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-mchenry-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Answer (score 22):

I have noticed more and more, both his *and* her being used, not alternatively by paragraph as another suggested, but within larger divisions of the the writing. For example, in a baby book, which covers many, many topics, each topic will use either his or her exclusively.  It seems to be a fairly even balance, and not confusing to the reader.

Comment: I like this approach. But it can't be used in short prose.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a comprehensive answer from [Oxford Dictionaries Website](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/he-or-she-versus-they):

> What should you do in sentences such as these?
>   If your child is thinking about a gap year, ? can get good advice from this website.
>   ...

Four different solutions are discussed:

> If your child is thinking about a gap year, he can get good advice from this website.
>   If your child is thinking about a gap year, he or she can get good advice from this website.
>   If your children are thinking about a gap year, they can get good advice from this website.
>   If your child is thinking about a gap year, they can get good advice from this website.

OD advocates the usage of "they" as a singular pronoun and repels the argument that such usage is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: OD mixes up a non-specific indefinite person and a specific definite person.
Please read my answer(there are two answers of mine. I mean the new one).

Comment: @ivanhoescott: *Your child*, when you are writing an article addressed to all parents on the Internet (or even just ones from the U.K.), is ***clearly*** a non-specific indefinite person. And if you're talking to some specific parent, you probably wouldn't say *your child*, you would say *Laura* and use the pronoun *she*.

Answer (score 15):

Either of your suggestions is appropriate in formal written text, with "his" a much more common formulation.  "Their" is even more common, but less accepted in the most highly pedantic communities.

If you want to avoid the question altogether, as nohat suggests, simply drop the pronoun. "Each student should save questions until the end" is perfectly standard.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't say `That's what said` instead of `That's what he/she said`.

Answer (score 14):

There is noteworthy precedent for *it* in Shakespeare's *A Midsummer Night's Dream,* where Oberon tells Puck about the magic purple flower:

> The juice of it on sleeping eyelids laid
>  Will make or man or woman
>   madly dote
>  Upon the next live creature that **it** sees.

The rejection or even revulsion that this obvious solution provokes (as does the old-fashioned use of this same pronoun for an infant) suggests that we hold the person/thing distinction sacred, far more important even than the male/female distinction. Would that our culture more generally bore out that suggestion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100350/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-donovan-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Answer (score 11):

Novelist [Anthony Burgess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Burgess) suggested that a gender-neutral, all-inclusive, singular subject pronoun could be formed by combining she, he and it, to form *shit*. Following this formula, the gender-neutral, all-inclusive, singular possessive pronoun would combine her, his and its, to form *hist*:

> Each student should save hist questions until the end.

The beauty of this is that no grammatical accommodation would have to be made for the robot students of the future.

Answer (score 11):

**October 2017**

5.48: Singular *they* (footnote from the *Chicago Manual of Style Online* **October 2017**)

> The generic singular *they* was endorsed in **2015** by the editors of the *Washington Post*, though with a caveat to first try avoiding it if possible. Singular *they* is more likely to be accepted in British than in American English. See Bas Aarts, *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2010), (“the use of the plural pronoun they with a non-specific singular antecedent [is] sanctioned by widespread current usage.)

*The Washington Post* ran this article by Travis M. Andrews on **28 March 2017**:

> The Associated Press Stylebook, arguably the foremost arbiter of grammar and word choice in journalism, has added an entry for “they” as a singular, gender-neutral pronoun in its latest edition.

The description of the singular *they* below is from 5.48 of the *Chicago Manual of  Style Online*.

> Normally, a singular antecedent requires a singular pronoun. But because *he* is no longer universally accepted as a generic pronoun referring to a person of unspecified gender, people commonly (in speech and in informal writing) substitute the third-person-plural pronouns *they, them, their* , and *themselves* (or the nonstandard singular *themself*.
>
> While this usage is accepted in those spheres, it is only lately showing signs of gaining acceptance in formal writing, where Chicago recommends avoiding its use.
> When referring specifically to a person who does not identify with a gender-specific pronoun, however, *they* and its forms are often preferred. (*They* used in this sense was the American Dialect Society’s Word of the Year for 2015.) Like singular *you*, singular *they* takes a plural verb. So when the context requires it, *they/them/their/theirs*, like *you/your/yours* (long used as both singular and plural forms), can be used to refer to one person {they have a degree in molecular biology} {their favorite color is blue}. And *themself* (like *yourself*) may be used to signal the singular antecedent (though some people will prefer *themselves*) {they blamed themself [or themselves]}. A number of other gender-neutral singular pronouns are in use, invented for that purpose; forms of these are usually singular and take singular verbs. In general, a person’s stated preference for a specific pronoun should be respected.

Answer (score 9):

*Before I answer I wish to state that I am a proud supporter of the LGBTQ+ community and don't particularly care what pronoun anyone prefers or chooses for themself, as long as it makes them feel comfortable and respected.*

---

With the risk of seeming a bit flippant in my answer:  **No, there is NOT a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun.**

And, in support of my answer, I point to all of the confusion and attempts to answer this question above.

Languages evolve slowly as products of their time, people who speak them, and the needs to describe both.  Until very recently, English has not had need of a gender-neutral singular pronoun because societal attitudes did not require such.  It was generally accepted that you were the gender/sex you biologically demonstrated at birth.  Rare cases of ambiguous sex due to biological/developmental deformities aside, this is how *most* speakers of English were content to view the world.  Binary usages like *his/her*, were not offensive to most speakers.  And, in cases where people wanted an alternative, the most common uses were the *singular they* or *one* substitutions.  Other past attempts at coining a new system were largely ignored, laughed at, or downright rejected as unnecessary.

The past few decades have seen quite a shift in our understanding of and attitudes towards human sexuality and gender identity.  [Homosexuality has been declassified as a mental disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_DSM) (it was listed as such as recently as DSMIII).  Sexuality is no longer seen as a binary, tertiary or even quaternary state.  We accept that people are heterosexual, homosexual, bisexual, pansexual, and myriad other orientations and preferences.  What was once taboo to even mention in public can now be discussed airily on a sitcom...

*Likewise, our societal understanding of gender has begun to evolve.* The word *transgender* has entered the public consciousness in more than a small way. We're only beginning to adapt to the notion that people's gender exhibits similar fluidity to that of sexuality.  And, as such, our language is still unequipped to properly handle this.

What will be the chosen gender-neutral singular pronoun?  I'll be damned if I know.  But, I do know **we currently don't have one**.

For now, *unless the person in question directs me to do otherwise*, I will continue to use the *singular they* until an alternative gathers enough steam to supplant it.  Unfortunately, languages evolve far slower than society does, so I don't recommend that you hold your breath waiting.

Comment: "Before I answer I wish to state that I am a proud supporter of the LGBTQ+ community and don't particularly care what pronoun anyone prefers or chooses for *themself*". I love how you open with this then try to argue against it.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen (and used in one job) a recommendation to switch between "his" and "her", switching each paragraph.

I don't mean to imply that you should change the gender of a singular individual across paragraphs. I mean that you'd be talking about a new person in each paragraph, but with a different gender than the previous.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100347/discussion-on-answer-by-craig-buchek-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Answer (score 6):

*I already posted an answer to the question.
While discussing with a commenter for my answer, I found a clearer explanation for my assertions.
So I think it deserves another answer*.

When discussing the subject, it is important to distinguish between a non-specific indefinite person and a specific definite person, though many people don't seem to realize this.
The examples of the former: everyone, anyone, someone, no one, etc.
The examples of the latter: the murderer in a certain murder case, the author of a letter/novel/academic paper, etc.

I claim the following assertions.

1. Referring to a non-specific indefinite person as *they* is grammatical, at least in informal writing or conversation.
2. Referring to a specific definite person as *they* is ungrammatical.

Here is the explanation.

Consider the following sentence:

> *Everyone knows each other.*

I searched the Corpus of the Contemporary American English (COCA) for this sentence.
It returned 7 results.

I searched for the sentence by [Google Books](https://www.google.co.jp/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22everyone%20knows%20each%20other%22&tbm=bks).
It returned 11,800 results.

So I think it is safe to say that the sentence is grammatical at least in an informal writing or conversation.
Note that *each other*, as is well known, requires a semantically plural subject,
while *everyone* is morphosyntactically singular.
It follows that semantic plurality and morphosyntactic singularity are compatible in English.
Hence the sentence *Everyone did their best* is grammatical.

Now consider the following sentence:

> *Leslie knows each other.*

This is ungrammatical because *Leslie*, which is the name of a person, is both semantically and
morphosyntactically singular.
Likewise the sentence *Leslie did their best* is ungrammatical.

#### References

["Everyone knows each other"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=89) by Geoffrey K. Pullum

["Everybody Has Their Own Opinion About the Singular *They*"](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/June05Eye.pdf) by John Lawler

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100348/discussion-on-answer-by-ivanhoescott-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Simply change to 3rd person plural, so you are referring to everyone: *they/them/their.*

> Each student should save their questions until the end.

or

> Every student should save their questions until the end.

Both are grammatically correct, and gender neutral.

Comment: Both *each* and *every* are singular.

Comment: I was referring to the pronouns They/Them/Their in the examples. 'Their' is a 3rd person pronoun, that is used both as a plural, and occasionally as a singular term. http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/third-person-pronouns/

Answer (score 2):

I have read several articles on "*singular they*" and found that most authors don't distinguish
a **non-specific indefinite** person from a **specific definite** person on the issue.

Examples of the former are: *everybody*, *anybody*, *somebody*, *nobody*, *each person*, etc.
Examples of the latter are: the murderer in a certain murder case, the author of an anonymous letter or a novel,
the foreign author of a novel or an academic paper, etc.

There are many examples of singular they referring to a **non-specific indefinite** person in the classic literature.

On the other hand, it seems to me that examples of singular they referring to a **specific definite** person are almost non-existent in the literature.

I think that the use of singular they referring to a **non-specific indefinite** person is grammatical,
but the use of such a pronoun referring to a **specific definite** person is not necessarily so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100349/discussion-on-answer-by-ivanhoescott-is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular).

Comment: Either I need some clarification, or your assertion seems wrong. I don't see any issue with the statement "the murderer went to the store, then they went home", which is one of your examples of a **specific definite** person, but singular they doesn't seem any different there.

Answer (score -1):

His is correct. All others are for specific cases only. There has been some political motivation in recent years to change it, but it is what it is.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. The singular "they" dates back to the 14th century.