# Does "get a diagnosis" imply you think the result will be positive?

Tags: meaning, connotation

If x said to someone

> I want to get a diagnosis for Parkinson's

Does that imply that x already believes they have Parkinson's and want confirmation, or does it just imply that x wants a result no matter whether it is positive or negative?

Comment: Read 'test' in place of 'diagnosis' -- there are **no** presumptions implied.

Comment: one gets a test ... diagnosis is a result!  I suspect OP meant test.  Many answers ensued.

Answer (score 5):

Getting a [*diagnosis*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diagnosis) means *identifying or determining* the nature/cause of a disease or condition through evaluation. The word is derived from the Greek dia- (apart) + gignōskein, to come to know, discern. Though a diagnosis is neither positive or negative (aside from the fact that there exists a condition/illness, which is rarely *positive*) people may fear them because they want to be well, not ill.

> I want to get a diagnosis for Parkinson's

People don't usually shop for a particular diagnosis, so it would be unusual for someone to put it this way (it does happen regarding disability/insurance/legal compensation, or because they desire a particular medication or treatment, that people want their preferred diagnosis confirmed.)

Having said that, I would think *x* suspects they may have Parkinson's and wants certainty of whether they have the disease or not (not expecting to be proven wrong, but likely wanting to have an answer.) In this case, they are more likely to express it as,

> I suspect I have Parkinson's. I'm here to get a diagnosis/have my suspicion confirmed or ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the person thinks, is afraid of having Parkinson's, so he/she is looking for a scientific support for his/her fears. The diagnosis may be positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

I concur that a diagnosis itself is neither positive or negative; however, the interpretation of the diagnosis by the recipient (patient) can be positive or negative. That said, there is no implication either way involved in the phrase "get a diagnosis." That is merely describing an act.