# Using 'they' with indefinite article

Tags: articles

Is this sentence correct?

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, they can request a reassignment.

Is it correct to use 'they' when talking about 'an employee'? Or should the subject be plural?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the accepted stance on using "they" in a singular form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/what-is-the-accepted-stance-on-using-they-in-a-singular-form)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that your example is correct.

A plural subject has a slightly different meaning, leaning towards more than one employee with an ethical dilemma:

> If employees experience an ethical dilemma, *they* can request a reassignment

Using *they* as shown in your example is a relatively recent literary device used to address the issue of gender assumption; e.g.:

1. The classic gender assumption of masculine, with the implication that men work and women don't:

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, *he* can request a reassignment

2. Using "he or she" to make it gender-neutral. A little clumsy:

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, *he or she* can request a reassignment

3. Using "she or he," an alternative that puts ladies first. Equally clumsy:

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, *she or he* can request a reassignment

4. In some writings, you may see the gender assumed as feminine:

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, *she* can request a reassignment

5. Another solution you may see in textbooks is for authors to alternate between he and she, like so:

> MATH HOMEWORK:
>
> 1. If a student rides their bike at 10mph for 15 minutes, how far will *he* travel?
> 2. If someone walks for at 5mph, how far will *she* walk in an hour?
> 3. A friend walks for 45 minutes at 3mph. How far will *he* walk?
> 4. If a person drives at 20mph, how far will *she* drive in an hour?
> 5. etc.

As you can see, *they* neatly sidesteps all of this clumsiness, effectively leaving it as an exercise to the reader to assign gender.

> If an employee experiences an ethical dilemma, *they* can request a reassignment

Comment: It's not as recent as you think, but it has become more popular recently.