# Can "his/her" be replaced by "his"?

Tags: pronouns, writing, possessives, singular-they

Yesterday, I asked this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/if-a-facebook-user-dies-what-happens-to-the-account) on Web Apps:

> If a Facebook user dies, what happens
>   to **the** account?

Actually, I wanted to ask it this way:

> If a Facebook user dies, what happens
>   to **his/her** account?

I chose the easy way and used **the** instead of **his/her**. Could I use just **his** in this case?:

> If a Facebook user dies, what happens
>   to **his** account?

What would you recommend for similar cases? Which pronoun is more appropriate to be used?

Comment: Related: [Is it correct to use “their” instead of “him or her”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-him-or-her)

Comment: Abominations like "his/her" should never be used, so yes: it \*must\* be replaced by something, anything. Even "donut" would be better than that. *"If a Facebook user dies, what happens to **donut** account?"* While this makes no sense, it's still better than that politically-braindamaged fake word.

Comment: The biggest problem with the English language is the lack of a gender-neutral personal pronoun.

Comment: @Nellius: English has one. "they/them". Use it, you'll like it. :)

Comment: @Mr. Shiny "they/them" is a plural, not a singular. It is often used LIKE a singular because English does not a have a gender-neutral singular personal pronoun (like "on" in french, for example)

Comment: @Nellius: No, it has both a singular and plural meaning, just like "you" does.

Comment: Also at [Is using 'he' as a gender-neutral third-person pronoun correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct). The original is at [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ... his vs her vs their?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the singular “**their**”: “*what happens to **their** account*”.

While is was regarded with rather less than more favorability in the past by style guides, it is gender-neutral and, as such, regains popularity.

Answer (score 13):

Using "**their**" is probably the best alternative if you insist on avoiding "**his**". The downside is that it implies plural and sounds slightly awkward.

I consider using "**his**" in a gender-neutral context still acceptable. If somebody takes offense at common pronoun usage (with broad historic precedent), they're actively nitpicking for reasons to get offended, with no intent of having a productive discussion.

The unwieldy construction "**his/her/whatever-the-pronoun-is-for-transgender**" is drawing attention away from your topic to gender issues. Good to avoid unless you're specifically writing on gender.

Your example of using "**the**" is actually changing semantics of the sentence. It amounts to rephrasing, not just simple replacement of a pronoun.

> Alex died without depositing money to Drew's account. If Alex dies, what happens to **the** account?

In this example, "**the**" denotes Drew's account. However, any pronoun (his/her/their) would denote Alex's own account.

Comment: using "their" in this example is not implying plural. It is a "Singular They".

Comment: @Mr Shiny and New: And the pronouns 'you/you/yours' proves it.

Comment: Singular they in an indefinite sense (as here) is ancient and utterly uncontroversial. You'll find [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) going back hundreds of years. And for what it's worth, many modern [style guides](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/grammar/singular-they) are clear that you should not use "his" in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that 'they/them/their' is and has been for a good long time a grammatical and reasonable [more reasonable than 'his'] use with grammatically singular but notionally plural pronouns.

The 'his' alternative was an artificial construct that was meant to try to stop what was a natural language use. What's worse, it attempted to end the use of 'they/them/their' based on a misconception about English pronouns.

> Grammar Puss
>   ...
>
> Sometimes  an alleged grammatical
>   "error" is logical not only in the
>   sense of "rational," but in the sense
>   of respecting distinctions made by 
>   the  logician. Consider this alleged
>   barbarism:      Everyone returned to
>   their seats.      If anyone calls,
>   tell them I can't come to the phone.
>   No one should have to sell their home
>   to pay for medical care.
>
> The mavens explain: [everyone] means
>   [every one], a singular subject, which
>   may not serve as the antecedent of a 
>   plural  pronoun  like  [them]  later 
>   in  the sentence.  "Everyone  returned
>   to [his] seat," they insist.  "If
>   anyone calls, tell [him] I can't come
>   to the phone."    If you were the 
>   target  of  these  lessons,  you 
>   might  be  getting  a  bit
>   uncomfortable.    [Everyone  returned 
>   to  his  seat] makes it sound like
>   Bruce Springsteen was discovered
>   during intermission  to  be  in  the 
>   audience,  and everyone rushed back
>   and converged on his seat to await an
>   autograph.  If there is a good chance
>   that a caller may be female, it is odd
>   to ask  one's  roommate to  tell 
>   [him]  anything  (even  if you are not
>   among the people who get upset about
>   "sexist language"). Such feelings of 
>   disquiet  --  a  red  flag  to  any
>   serious  linguist -- are well-founded.
>
> The logical point that everyone but
>   the language mavens intuitively grasps
>   is that [everyone] and  [they]  are 
>   not  an antecedent and a pronoun
>   referring to the same person in the
>   world, which would force them to agree
>   in number. They are a "quantifier" and
>   a "bound  variable," a different
>   logical relationship. [Everyone
>   returned to their seats] means "For
>   all X, X returned to X's seat."  The
>   "X" is simply  a  placeholder  that 
>   keeps track of the roles that players
>   play across different relationships:
>   the X that comes back to a seat is the
>   same X that owns the seat that  X 
>   comes  back  to. The  [their]  there 
>   does  not,  in fact, have plural
>   number, because it refers neither to
>   one thing nor to many things; it does
>   not refer at all.
>
> On  logical grounds,  then,  variables
>   are  not  the  same  thing  as  the 
>   more  familiar "referential" pronouns
>   that trigger agreement ([he] meaning
>   to some  particular guy,  [they] 
>   meaning  some  particular  bunch  of 
>   guys).  Some  languages are
>   considerate and offer their speakers
>   different words for  referential 
>   pronouns and for variables. But
>   English is stingy; a referential
>   pronoun must be drafted into service
>   to lend its name when a speaker needs
>   to use a variable.  There is no 
>   reason  that  the vernacular decision
>   to borrow [they, their, them] for the
>   task is any worse than the
>   prescriptivists' recommendation of
>   [he,  him,  his]. Indeed, [they] has
>   the advantage of embracing both sexes
>   and feeling right in a wider variety
>   of sentences.

http://pinker.wjh.harvard.edu/articles/media/1994_01_24_thenewrepublic.html

Answer (score -1):

It’s a matter of choice. A traditional English usage is the common gender **his**. If you don’t mind abuse from the pronoun police, use that. If not, be prepared to revise your text every week to accommodate someone who is now offended by what had previously been considered “inclusive”.

Comment: Singular "they/their" is found in Tyndale and the King James Bible and many great English writers. It's traditional.

Comment: @StuartF — but not the exclusive form. I’ve edited my answer to replace “the” by “a”. Will that satisfy you?

Comment: There are still people who insist that a sentence should never end with a preposition, it doesn't mean they're right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — It was not I that was being dogmatic, I wrote that it was a matter of choice. Dogmatism is something up with which I will not put!

Comment: "It was not I who was being dogmatic..." :)

Comment: A ten-year old answer to this question, with a significant number of upvotes, already says 'If somebody takes offense at common pronoun usage (with broad historic precedent), they're actively nitpicking for reasons to get offended, with no intent of having a productive discussion'. Are you saying anything different from what is already in that answer?

Comment: The [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their/55466#55466) by Jay to a related question contains a fair summary of the full range of viewpoints, including this one, that can be held on this matter.

Comment: @jsw29 — My answer does not discuss the motives etc of persons who take offence at the alternative I mention, but merely warned of the possible reception. I do not see an answer that focuses on “his”. I am answering this question and not a related question. If this is a duplicate question, vote to close it. If not SE does not require me to search for related questions.

Comment: @ColleenV — :-) But the usage of that instead of who in speech (and quick fire comments) must be epidemic. Ngram would tell I suppose.

Comment: I am most definitely pitching stones from my glass house, but I couldn't help myself.