# Need to clarify use of "its" and "their"

Tags: adjectives, singular-they

I am having a debate at work regarding the correct choice:

> No investor has ever lost its capital.

or

> No investor has ever lost their capital.

It seems to sound awkward to say "its capital" as opposed to "their capital".  We are referring to a single investor (in a context where *all* investors are institutional entities).

Comment: "event lost their..."? Neither alternative is appealing, though the latter is slightly preferable to the former (unless the single investor is a corporation!) I would suggest "No investor ever lost capital" presumably followed by something like "by investing with us" or "by following these guidelines"

Comment: There might be (largely pointless) debate over [his/her/their](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/can-his-her-be-replaced-by-his), but this one is just too basic. I'm now flagging such questions "too localised", because they're only relevant to questioners with very limited familiarity with English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A while ago (I tried to find the related question but failed) there was disagreement about this between native English speakers (comments were on fire). How do you expect non-native speakers to be able to handle it?

Comment: @Irene: I don't follow you. Surely you don't mean there was extended debate on whether a noun like "investor" is *normally* referenced by the inanimate pronoun "it"? OP here is clearly not thinking in terms of *institutional investors* like banks and pension funds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was referring to the question you provided the link for. I believe that OP's confusion stems, at least partly, from the fact that "they" with a singular verb sounds strange to foreigners, so they are looking for alternatives, wondering all the way if they are doing the right thing.

Comment: @Irene: oic. I didn't really put that link in for OP's benefit anyway. Dilip Sarwate's comment had already indicated a plausible context for neuter "it's" (where I'd prefer "their" anyway). In most circumstances (and the first definition in any dictionary, I'm sure) "investor" normally indicates a person rather than an organisation. That's why "it's" sounds strange, even to people who don't like using "their" with a singular referent. OP still hasn't clarified his intended meaning of "investor", so I stand by my interpretation that it's the default one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not sure if you are implying that this question is too ridiculous to come from someone quite familiar with English (such as a native speaker). This question is a result of a heated debate in my office with all Americans. Our clients span the globe and we were trying to determine the best answer. Are we not allowed to submit questions without being critized for using this forum for questions that may seem to you too basic?

Comment: @Shannon: Of course you're allowed to submit your question. But note that you still haven't clarified that **vital** element of context (is your single investor a person or an organisation?). Surely you can see that the reason people are uneasy about "it's" is because the natural interpretation is "investor=person"? If your clients are **all** companies you have a possible case for ignoring that unease and just using "it's" anyway, but if not, what is unclear after checking out my link?

Comment: ...OOOPS! - I just checked out my own link! Sorry - it should have been [Is it correct to use “their” instead of “his or her”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her). I AM SORRY!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  These are all institutional entities.

Comment: @Shannon: I've edited that info into the question (not everyone will read this far down the extended comment chain). Had I realised that in the first place I wouldn't have voted to close, but I'm not going to beat myself up about it because if you'd been talking about it with people in the office you *must/should* have known that was crucial. The answer now is that logically/grammatically of course you can use "it's", but it'll sound odd to many people simply because it's an unusual usage, incorrect in most *other* contexts. Personally I'd just sidestep the whole issue by using *their* anyway.

Comment: You can’t really use it for a human agency. It is not actually neuter in English.  English doesn't have neuters. It has animate and inanimate, and only once animate can male or female be assigned.  No one asks whether the mare has had "its" foal yet. And no human being can ever be an it. If you don't know what their gender is, use they, which at least doesn't preclude the agent being animate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers PLEASE could people not use _it's_ in place of _its_ as in "....for neuter "it's (where I'd...." **or** "...uneasy about "it's" is because..." **or** "...of course you can use "it's"....", especially when fine points are being debated?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: Don't blow a fuse! It's not like I don't *no* what's rite! Their only commence, and we all make misteaks now and then. You shirley dont want me watching you like a hawk forever and a day here on ELU weighting for you to slip up!

Comment: @tchrist: I think you are mistaken there. Henry is correct in saying OP can correctly use **its** *if and only if* **all** investors are "non-human". And a bank *can* invest, so it's perfectly valid to say [the bank is an investor](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22babk+is+an+investor%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#pq=%22bank+is+an+investor%22&hl=en&ds=bo&cp=5&gs_id=r&xhr=t&q=%22the+bank+is+an+investor%22&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%22the+bank+is+an+investor%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c74deb9746404bf2&biw=1578&bih=836)

Comment: @Shannon: Okay, I can't undo my (unduly precipitate) vote to close, but you've managed to generate a more interesting debate about the gender of "investor" than that boring business about whether Microsoft is singular or plural, so I've reversed my (also precipitate) downvote against the question. Not to mention that without this question I'd never have picked up on John Lawler's singular observation on the status of **no investor** as neither singular nor plural. So - many thanks for that, and apologies again for the bungled link before!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not blowing a fuse. Occasional occurrences of _it's_ when _its_ was intended can be attributed to proof-reading error; repeated misuse is another matter. Your reputation is high enough that you are likely a moderator of this stackexchange (certainly you have the power to close questions) and your writings carry great weight. So please keep in mind that if a clock strikes thirteen, the thirteenth stroke is not only wrong by itself, but it also casts some doubt on the validity of the previous twelve; and the fourteenth, fifteenth,.. strokes just add to the cloud of suspicion.

Answer (score 6):

No problem. [Singular *they*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf) covers this situation perfectly.

Note, by the way, that the Noun Phrase *no investor* is **neither** singular **nor** plural - it's ***Zero***.
Zero is not one and it's not more than one. So assigning `Singular` to it is purely arbitrary,
no matter how many investors there are.

The point is thus not whether *no investor* is singular or plural, but rather that
*no investor* is ***non-referential***. That's the kind of Noun Phrase [that singular *they* gets used with](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?cat=27).

Comment: Nor, I might add, after viewing the discussion above, is it the point whether _no investor_ is neuter or human. _They/their/them_ is completely appropriate in all these cases -- _legal real humans, real legal humans, illegal real humans, animals, things, Martians,_ whatever.

Comment: +1 for opening my eyes to the non-singular, non-plural status of "no investor". But I'd like to give you a -1 at the same time for doing my head in over whether there even **is** a word for "singularity/plurality status" - and if so, what the hell is it?

Comment: _Number_. Singular number, plural number, dual number, paucal number. Person, number, gender, and case are the usual inflectional categories for Latin nouns (and adjectives; the Romans didn't distinguish them, since they behaved the same morphologically).

Comment: oic. So here on ELU "number category" or "number class" (in quotes) might be a reasonable way of indicating what some people see as a difference between "its" and "their"? I like that "paucal number" - never come across it before.

Comment: Nah, just ***Number***; no "category" or "class" needed; it just confuses things. _Singular_ is short for _singular number_, after all, just like _Accusative_ is short for _accusative case_, and nobody would say "case class" here, would they? (I hope :-)

Answer (score 1):

We tend not to use "its" for people. One would say

> No investor has ever lost his or her capital.

or more simply

> No investor has ever lost their capital.

although "their" as a gender-neutral singular possessive is not universally accepted.

Comment: The OP actually clarified that they are not talking about people. "These [investors] are all institutional entities."

Answer (score 1):

I think *its* is fine only if all investors are neuter, such as companies or pension funds.  It fails if any of them are human.

For me *their* works in these situations.  Others may disagree

But you can avoid the "singular they" and gender issues by saying

> No investors have ever lost their capital.

Comment: No, an investor is a person, and a person can never be an it.  An it is marked as inanimate. Persons are animate. "It" doesn't mean neuter in English, you know.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you will find [Google is an investor in Zynga](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Google+is+an+investor+in+Zynga%22).  *It* is an investor in other companies too.

Comment: Google is hardly a person now, are they?

Comment: @Henry: I'm sure you don't need me to defend your corner, but have an upvote anyway. And consider [we are an investor](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22babk+is+an+investor%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22we+are+an+investor%22&pbx=1&oq=%22we+are+an+investor%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=114411l119112l2l119594l17l16l0l0l0l0l192l1788l9.7l16l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c74deb9746404bf2&biw=1578&bih=836), which I've no doubt was invariably written in a context where "we" is in fact a company, not a monarch using the "regal 'we'".

Answer (score 1):

To me, `their` just reads better, even knowing all investors are institutional entities. There is nothing wrong with `its` though (provided it's entirely clear you're not talking about individuals). This is purely a question of style.