# Is using "he" for a gender-neutral third-person correct?

Tags: pronouns, singular-they, gender-neutral, political-correctness, generic-they

I know there are different opinions on this issue. My question: Is using "he" for a general, gender-neutral third person still in common use for formal writing? By common use I mean, can I expect my paper not to be penalised because I use "he" as pronoun for "a student", etc.?

I think "he/she" is too clumsy and I am not comfortable with singular they.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gender neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun); see also [Reason for the current trend to use "she" as a gender-neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun); [Using "they" for person of unknown sex](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/using-they-for-person-of-unknown-sex).

Comment: This question deals specifically with the acceptability of "he". Those questions deal with "they", "she", or gender neutral pronoun in general.

Comment: Those questions treat about gender neutral pronouns, and especially the main one treats about both, so yours is more or less included. Note that it's a "possible" duplicate for now, meaning that if other don't vote, it will stay open. Democracy wins! :D

Comment: @Alenanno: I have read the answers to those other questions, and I couldn't find any answer about the acceptability of *he/his* in formal writing. So this question isn't a duplicate. If I missed it, please quote.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question as you asked it, but I believe it helps with the "gender" problem in question. In such cases I generally use "she" instead of "he" or "he/she". It's still as simple as using "he".

Comment: I now always use _they_ without worrying. It's been in use for centuries, and it sounds perfectly acceptable to native speakers (British English). Anyone who objects is so formal as to be antediluvian, IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Comment: I'm pulling for "his" to resurface to mean "its," as in "Love alone his watch is keeping. all through the night." Meanwhile, somebody should tell the poster the answer to {his, her, their} question is that {he, she,they} should try not to distract the reader the way I have just done.. Pick a style appropriate to the subject  and the audience and stick to it, but not doggedly.Someone once said to me, "If you were my gender, you'd understand." I relied,"Words have gender. You and I have sex, " and they stormed out of the room. Replace "they" with "he" or "she" and see if it changes my story..

Comment: How can "he" possibly be gender  neutral? The use of "she" instead of he is merely an attempt to make up for the "patriarchal" oppression. But she is not gender neutral either. I cannot believe I am having to spell this out. Also, one wonders what the actual context is here. Answering questions in a context void is silly and a waste of time. There are online guides for writing in a gender-neutral way by changing how one's structure's one sentences....they is fine for some sentences, it would not necessarily work across the board.

Answer (score 21):

Its correctness, as with any language usage, will depend on your audience. In England, in most formal writing, using "he" in this context would communicate that you were either unaware of contemporary good usage, or deliberately flouting it.

[Edit, prompted by the OP:] For example, from the [Transport for London editorial style guide](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/corporate/TfLEditorialStyleGuide.pdf) (a major municipal highways authority & public transport operator with a multi-billion pound (dollar/euro) turnover:

> Avoid giving offence by using outdated
>   or patronising terms and **include
>   references to gender only when it is
>   essential**. Using the plural can be
>   helpful: customers; local people;
>   employees

(my emphasis)

[Edit 2] Similarly, from the [Training and Development Agency for Schools style guide](http://www.tda.gov.uk/about/editorialstyleguide.aspx):

> **they, he/she**
>
> Use **they** in preference to he/she: **if
>   the candidate passes the test, they
>   should...** If possible, try to avoid
>   using gender specific pronouns, e.g.
>   **candidates who pass the test should…**

(emphasis in the original)

Comment: Can you cite any reputable source/guidelines saying that it's not recommended?

Comment: Both links are dead now, and how authoritative/widely applicable is the style guide of a public transport operator?

Answer (score 17):

The question admits no simple answer.  Moreover, only by an effort can one disentangle the answer from politics, and even then not wholly.  Nevertheless, let us make the effort and try.

**Why to prefer *he***

On the one hand, English is a Germanic language, which means among others that it has never sought a complete set of unambiguous pronouns.  A Germanic language distinguishes pronouns extensively by context.  For a famous example, consider the modern German *sie,* "she," and *Sie*, "you" (formal), the two words capitalized differently (though not so at the beginning of a sentence) but always pronounced alike.  Whereas in English, it is she that has her own, distinctive pronoun; in modern German it is *er,* he.

Clumsy?  Maybe.  But that's Germanism for you, with roots as deep as Herodotus' tales of the frozen forests of the dim, Germanic north.  You cannot alter the essential way the Germanic languages approach pronouns but by uprooting the language family entire.  The pattern is etched in the languages' bones.

At any rate, on Germanic grounds, the preferred pronoun in the sex-indefinite semantical singular would be *he.*

**Why to prefer *they***

On the other hand, unlike modern German, English does admit a peculiar but nevertheless respectable, centuries-old alternative to *he* in the sex-indefinite semantical singular.  This alternative is *they.*

The use of *they* in the sex-indefinite semantical singular is admittedly soft because it thrashes English grammatical number—as in, "A ship's captain *is* responsible for everything that happens on board.  They *are* not allowed excuses."  Fortunately, the practical use of *they* in the semantical singular usually (though not always) proves more congenial than in it does in contrived examples like the one I have just given.  Unobjectionable examples of the following kind are rather more typical:  "Each writer will choose the pronoun they think suits the context."  (You might still prefer *he,* which is fine; but one cannot characterize *they* as wrong here.)

Both alternatives for the sex-indefinite semantical singular, *he* and *they*, have long been attested by good writers.  Both can and probably should be used, even in the same literary work.

**The use and misuse of *she***

In recent decades, we have sometimes seen less good writers force *she* into the role of the sex-indefinite semantical singular.  This fad represents not English style but political agitprop and should never voluntarily be done except to achieve a specific political effect.  Use *he or she* rather, if you must, as the *emphatically* sex-indefinite semantical singular.

You will hear some good writers deprecate the three-word pronounal *he or she,* but you should understand what they probably, actually mean—and do not mean—by deprecating it.   It is doubtful that a good writer deprecates *he or she* when the sex-indefinite nature of the pronoun calls for particular emphasis.  Moreover, it can hardly be contested that today's world (for better or for worse) furnishes more subjects than formerly that call for *he or she.*  Still, most sex-indefinite subjects do not want such emphasis, and *he or she* is admittedly overused.

Regarding plain *she,* whose use we said was forced, we should note that not all uses of *she* in the sex-indefinite semantical singular actually are forced.  One can use *she* rather than *he* when the sex referenced is only quasi-indefinite, understood probably to be female.

**Recommendations**

As a default, prefer *he* to *they* for the sex-indefinite semantical singular, on the ground that Engish is a Germanic language and that *he* represents the better Saxon/German.

Though we have not yet mentioned it, on the uncommon occasion on which the matter arises, consider preferring *she* to *it* as the pronoun of personification (advice I have not actually followed in the answer you are reading, if only because I did not wish to distract the topic by beginning, "English is a Germanic language, which means that *she* has never sought a complete set of unambiguous pronouns").

**Other considerations**

In a college course, of course, the wise student will avoid bucking the instructor's sensibilities in the matter, whatever these sensibilities may be.  Even in the unlikely event that all you learn during the four months of the course is that you and the instructor disagree, by having given the instructor's way a fair trial, you will have established a sound, respectable right to your contrary opinion.  You will also have earned a high grade in the course.

Regarding language and politics, see [Orwell, George.  *Nineteen Eighty-four.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0452262933)

Comment: Back in the 1970's (when political feminism was less prevalent), some quasi-legal documents included statements such as "Throughout this document, the singular includes the plural, and the male includes the female." It was suggested that this should be changed to "the singular *embraces* the plural, and the male *embraces* the female."

Comment: @TrevorD Don’t you think that this whole “male embraces the female” thing sounds a bit dated in modern society?

Comment: @tchrist It was intended only as a jovial aside. I'm too old always to be able to judge what is 'dated'. But we've both got 1 upvote each, so we must be both right!

Comment: The downvotes make my point regarding the question's political entanglement. The answer is downvoted not because it is incorrect or misleading, but precisely because it is correct and informative. Go figure. The downvotes say more about the downvoters than about the merits of the answer.

Comment: Another good use of the allegedly "sexist" pronouns he and she is for describing interactions between multiple persons less ambiguously. If only one is of unknown gender, the writing is less ambiguous if the unknown gender is chosen opposite to the known one. If both are unknown a disclaimer may be needed that some would find clumsy ("In the following descriptions in this document, we will consistently use 'he' to refer to the student and 'she' to the professor. This does not imply any specific gender for the persons involved. [...] ")

Answer (score 15):

It's still considered acceptable. If you really want to cover your bases, include a definition at the front that reference to one gender imports all other genders, unless the context requires otherwise, and explain that you'll be using "he" for the sake of simplicity.

*Edit*: As per below discussion, using a single gender pronoun is not normally good style, although it is acceptable. The main reason to use it is when it's more important to avoid confusion about singular vs plural "they".

Comment: A disclaimer is a good idea

Comment: @Cerberus: I strongly disagree. It's a pretty outdated usage in most writing, except where it is important not to cause confusion about the use of "they".

Comment: Then let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Cerberus: I too will disagree with you here.  Firstly, it’s *definitely* not still *de rigueur* in any context — awkward circumlocutions like *he/she* have been acceptable for decades, and more promisingly, prejudice against the venerable singular *they* in formal writing is on the wane.  //  On the other hand, more subjectively, here’s why I prefer not to use *he* as a gender-neutral pronoun: [cont’d in next comment]

Comment: As you say, everyone knows conventional style, and no-one should read generic *he* as intentional sexism.  But there’s a fair bit of research on how things like this, *even when completely conventionalised*, contribute to shaping people’s perceptions and prejudices of gender.  The asymmetry of gender in conventional grammar and style is one of the many things reinforcing sexism in society.  Yes, it’s a small part, and in many cases would be impossible to change without brutally overhauling entire languages.  But this example is fairly egregious, and has a decent alternative; so why not change?

Comment: @PLL: I was on a bit of a rant there. But I do believe that many traditionalists still cling to *he*. I didn't mean at certain publishers or anything, just conservative circles. I know that *they* has a long history, possible dating back to the middle ages, which shouldn't come as a surprise. But the same objections were probably raised then by some. I didn't say anything about majorities or anything.

Comment: @PLL: As to this pet peeve of post-modernists, I am not quite convinced. Does it really affect our thinking? That is, does it affect us beyond reminding us of there mere fact of male dominance in the past? If you have a really convincing paper, I will be interested to read it. I've heard other theories; once a certain word becomes very common in a sense that deviates from its etymology, the old associations fade away soon enough, to a point where people do not realize the literal meaning of the word any more. Just as we do not think of terror any more when we call something *terrific*. ... =>

Comment: @PLL: Do you suppose that sexism is enforced less in England than on the Continent? German and Dutch use *he* and *his* for everything; but no-one sees it as a problem. The same applies to the Romance languages, I believe: while their possessive adjectives are gender neutral, they just use *il* etc. by default. And do you believe that people there think of women when they say *la présidence*, and of men with *le comité*? I think language is more complex than that. A bit of anecdotal evidence: I am a staunch feminist myself, glad that times have changed; and yet I strongly prefer *he*.

Comment: @Cerberus: German has gendered pronouns; dutch has a single masculine/feminine gender (plus the neuter gender). Accordingly, they do not "use he and his for everything".

Comment: @Marcin: But they do. You are confusing nouns with pronouns; only in the former are masculine and feminine mostly indistinguishable. It would be, *heeft iedereen zijn hoed gepakt?* (*zijn* = "his"), and *iemand doet maar wat hij wil* (*hij* = "he"). English is the only language that I know of that has this plural pronoun.

Comment: Marcin: I think by “…for everything”, @Cerberus didn’t mean “…in all cases”, but “…in the generic case, that covers everyone”.  French also uses generic *il*, and indeed goes further: the plural pronouns are gendered (*ils* and *elles*) and a mixed-gendered group is always *ils*.

Comment: @Cerberus: It is, of course, more complex than the example of la présidence -> women, la comitié -> men — I think you’re unfairly oversimplifying these arguments a bit there.  Lena Boroditsky’s work is what I was mainly thinking of; LL has discussed it several times, eg [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000129.html). She shows pretty convincingly that grammatical gender affects (not drastically, but quite significantly) the connotations we give to words: eg Spanish speakers are more apt to associate feminine-associated characteristics with bridges (*la puente*),

Comment: while for German speakers, the associations of *die Brücke* are more masculine.  The specific case of generic *he* (*hij*, *il*, …) I don’t know of any work on.  But there is lots of sociological work on how our image of a “generic person” tends to be male (try-this-at-home study: ask children to “draw a voter”, and count men vs. women in the results).  I’m sure that the generic use of “he” is much more an effect than a cause of this.  But in line with the sort of influence Boroditsky demonstrates, I’d be surprised if generic *he* doesn’t slightly contribute to reinforcing generic maleness.

Comment: I would be really interested to see research to confirm or debunk this extrapolation, but it’s hard to imagine how you would.  Perhaps: take some passage where a pronoun is being used generically, rewrite it with *he*, *they*, *he/she*, etc, ask participants to illustrate it (or something), and see how the sexes in the illustrations break down?  //  More generally… as you say, times have changed a lot so far, and I too am glad of that.  But there’s still a *hell* of a lot of sexism around, and much of it *is* at the non-intentional level.  Which is why I care about cases like this.

Comment: If you're going to use a disclaimer, then it needs to state that your including all gender and non gender individuals, not just those with gender. But you should just use the neutral they by default. There is no reason to retreat back to distinguish singular vs plural, people can do that from context

Answer (score 14):

**No, almost all English speakers and writers use "they."** I'd recommend doing the same, especially in formal writing.

A summary from Huddleston and Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002, p. 426 ('%' denotes acceptable in some dialects only):

> ***They*** is commonly used with a singular antecedent, as in *_Someone_ has left _their_ umbrella behind.* As such, it fills a gap in the gender system of the core personal pronouns by virtue of being
>   neutral as to sex. For some speakers singular ***they*** has a
>   distinct reflexive form *themself*: %*_Someone_ has locked _themself_
>   in the attic.* For discussion of singular ***they***, see the section
>   on gender, S17.2.4.

Further discussion including specific arguments against 'purportedly sex-neutral ***he***' and 'she' is found on pp. 491-495, noting they are **often systematically avoided** for good reasons, and marking them with the % sign ('grammatical in some dialect(s) only'). It also offers further avoidance strategies, including plural and first-person antecedents.

This question was specifically studied in 2009 by Collins Dictionaries for the Committee on Bible Translation. The conclusion is that the **plural generic** is almost universal and increasing, against masculine generic and other alternatives.

In particular, the masculine generic (he, his, himself, etc.) reduced from 22% to 8% between 1990 and 2009 while the plural/neutral (they, them, one, themselves, etc.) increased from 65% to 84%.

http://www.niv-cbt.org/information/collins-corpus-report/

> **1. Generic pronouns and determiners**
>
> This part of the study considered the types of pronouns and
>   determiners that are used to refer to indefinite pronouns (such as
>   someone, everybody and one) and non-gender specific nouns (such as a
>   person, each child and any teacher):
>
> A. masculine (he, his, himself, etc.); B. feminine (she, her, herself,
>   etc.); C. plural/gender-neutral (they, them, one, themselves, etc.);
>   D. alternative forms (s/he, him or her, his/her, etc.)
>
> In all the varieties of English analyzed, plural/neutral pronouns and
>   determiners account for the majority of usages.  Between 1990 and
>   2009, instances of masculine generic pronouns and determiners,
>   expressed as a percentage of total generic pronoun usage in general
>   written English, fell from 22% to 8%.
>
> e.g. ‘…when a person accepts unconditional responsibility, he denies
>   himself the privilege of “complaining” and “finding faults.”’
>
> Instances of ‘alternative’ generic pronouns and determiners fell from
>   12% to 8%.
>
> e.g. ‘Any citizen who wants to educate himself or herself has plenty
>   of sources from which to do so.’
>
> Instances of plural/neutral generic pronouns and determiners rose from
>   65% to 84%.
>
> e.g. ‘If you can identify an individual who metabolises nicotine
>   faster you can treat them more effectively.’
>
> Figures for the other corpora analyzed in the study are broadly
>   comparable with figures from the general written English corpus both
>   in overall magnitude and in the general trend over time.

Google Ngrams provides another view of the relative prevalence of these terms over time. The option ['he or she'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+or+she%2Che%2Cshe%2Cthey&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che+or+she%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20or%20she%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0) grew tenfold in the 70s (previously apparently legalese), peaked in the late 90s, and has been falling back again since. [This chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+or+she%2Che%2Cshe%2Cthey&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che+or+she%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20or%20she%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%3B%2Cc0) suggests that 'he or she' took over usage from both generic 'he' and generic 'they' (and replacement of masculine examples with feminine, boosting 'she' alone -- note this rough tool is measuring usage far broader than the generic). This indicates that the predominance of generic 'they' is not recent, but has a long tradition, far predating 'he or she.'

I'd personally consider masculine generic an archaic form, even before considering the important social reasons to prefer a gender-neutral alternative. But there are geographic locations (and maybe even academic fields) where you could expect your paper not to be penalised due to ongoing use of the masculine generic.

Comment: Great job referencing and quoting a source. Could you update your answer to specifically address the questioner's focus on formal writing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @quietquake. I'm not sure exactly what you mean, though, can you be more specific? Would highlighting the numbers help? Or are you is it more about "formal" writing?

Comment: I'm thinking specifically of the formal writing aspect. Maybe just add your own advice for the questioner's situation based on the source you're citing?

Answer (score 11):

Personally (and with the bias of a mid-western American English speaker), it sounds out-dated to use *he* or *she* in this case; the plural *they* avoids any gender bias. Alternatively, *you* also works as a replacement, however the tone may become too direct and commanding, which some may find disturbing.

Consider:

- In order to exit the parking garage, the driver must have the ticket that *he* received upon entry. *He* must then insert the card into the slot, whereupon the amount due will be displayed.
- In order to exit the parking garage, the driver must have the ticket that *they* received upon entry. *They* must then insert the card into the slot, whereupon the amount due will be displayed.
- In order to exit the parking garage, *you* must have the ticket that *you* received upon entry. *You* must then insert the card into the slot, whereupon the amount due will be displayed.

When writing formally or for a company or publication, always be sure to follow the recommended style guide; it may indicate which you should use. (It may also indicate that one should use "she" or alternate between "he" and "she" when referring to different people in order to ensure that one pronoun isn't overused.)

Comment: One can use "one" as a replacement for "you".

Comment: My case is a description, not an instruction, like "A student does blah blah blah". You or one will not work in that case.

Comment: @MT_Head what's about usage of him/her for "one" as per your suggestion?

Comment: Forget following the recommended style guide. Instead, talk to the company or publication about updating their style guide to be inclusive.

Comment: How embarrassing.

Comment: The advice to alternate "he" and "she" is just bad advice. It is agitprop. Good writers do not do it. Unless you aspire to inhabit Progressive bubble culture, avoid alternating "he" and "she."

Answer (score -3):

By definition:

HE

pronoun
used to refer to a man, boy, or male animal previously mentioned or easily identified.
"everyone liked my father—he was the perfect gentleman"
noun
1.
a male; a man.
"is that a he or a she?"

UNDERSTAND?

That very simply means that HE is GENDER SPECIFIC.   If a writer intends to be "GENDER NEUTRAL"  then use the proper word by definition.

Yes.  Writers can write anything they want meaning anything they want.  Writing is a tool used to make languages be read.
Yes.  Readers can read writing in anyway their single brain celled mind dictates.  Some will penalize, others not.

JUST WRITE IT CORRECTLY IN THE FIRST PLACE = FEWER ISSUES and most likely NO PENALTY.