# Default gender for pronouns

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using “he” for a gender-neutral third-person correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct)

I’m sure this is a duplicate, but I've heard that when the gender is unknown you are to use *he* instead of *he or she*.

Are there any references to support or discredit this?  If so, what is the rule?

Comment: English has no singular gender-neutral pronoun. For centuries, English speakers have used _he_ as the default. At the same time, they have also used the plural _they_ as well. There are no unbreakable grammar rules about this. It's strictly a matter of political correctness (PC). If you want to be PC, use the _they/their/them_ forms for singular persons of unknown gender. If you want to be PI (politically incorrect) for whatever reason, stick to the traditional use of _he_, but don't be surprised if someone accuses you of sexism or intellectual gerontism (ancient & petrified brain).

Comment: Using _she_ instead is becomming increasingly common.

Comment: @terdon: Stupidity, sexism, and PI come in all forms, don't they?

Comment: Not to worry; see [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf), for instance.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the singular-they question. This is "is *he* the default if you **don't** want to use either singular-they or 'he/she'?*, which is a totally different question.

Comment: @Marthaª The question asks if it's true that one should use "he" as the indeterminate gender pronoun and avoid "he or she". The dupe asks if it's true that one can use "their" to avoid "he or she". ***For all practical purposes they are the same question: what should one replace "he or she" with to be clear and grammatically correct.***

Comment: @MετάEd: no, this question is **not** asking what to replace "he or she" with. It's asking whether "he" is the default pronoun. I'm certainly under the impression that historically, it used to be, but I have no references to support this belief.

Comment: @Marthaª: Actually, anyone here over the age of 60 is reference enough. We were all taught that _he_ was the default pronoun when referring to a person of unknown gender. I agree with your understanding of the OP's question.

Comment: [This](http://genderneutralpronoun.wordpress.com/) could be interesting.

Comment: @BillFranke Anyone over 45 should be reference enough! But then perhaps my English teacher was of the generation who would have taught current 60-year-olds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using "he" for a gender-neutral third-person correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct) | Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun

Comment: The **reason** the English teachers taught us to use 'he' for the gender-neutral pronoun was that a lot of us were already using 'they', and that was considered wrong. If 'he' had been universally used before political correctness, the English teachers wouldn't have made such a big deal about it.

Comment: "They" as a third person singular indefinite pronoun is attested as early as 1382 in Wycliffe's Bible (also Chaucer, Caxton, etc), making it only slightly younger than the plural "they" in English, which was borrowed from Old Norse. Now unless you want to tell me that John Wycliffe was a feminist, I think it's rather clear that "political correctness" has absolutely nothing to do with it. It's also clear that "anyone over the age of __" arguments are equally fallacious. "They" is a perfectly acceptable grammatically correct 3rd person singular indefinite pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

'He' is no longer the default pronoun. Many authors of finance related books will make a brief note in the preface that when a generic person is involved, he (the author) will use the female pronoun. I don't believe the rules we had 40 years ago to stay with male pronouns still applies.

Side note - on the school public announcement system, "whoever lost their jacket...." as I was sitting in my high school English class, I remarked on the plural pronoun and was told it was accepted as an attempt to be gender neutral. It was an all boys school.

Comment: Using *he* is bad enough, but using *her* for a generic is still horribly jarring.  It's an in-your-fact thing where somebody is trying to score political points with their weird pronouns.

Comment: @tchrist - Feeling the way you do may reflect your background, age, etc. As a financial writer, with an audience that's contains more women that men, the female pronoun in that context doesn't feel contrived. Since, on average, men marry younger women, and, on average, men die younger, I'm addressing far more widows that widowers.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer damn that is bleak. but now I kinda get why some of my ux/web design books use her as the default pronoun.