# Are terms like "policeman" still gender-exclusive if they refer to one specific man?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, gender-neutral, political-correctness

I'm reading a news article about a male police officer and the author calls him a *policeman*. This word seems unsophisticated to me, but is it still sexist if it refers to a man?

Comment: Refers to a _man_? Wash your mouth out.

Comment: That’s why some people say *police officer*, since *police* is itself a *“plurale tantum”*, something of a defective class with no singular, and so must be used attributively to get at a singular sense for it.

Comment: Please see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct.

Comment: How is it sexist? He is a man who works for the police - Policeman is a perfectly good term. If the officer was a woman and the article called her a policewoman, would that be sexist too?

Comment: @tchrist: Depends on the dialect. Many inner cities in America have no trouble using *police* as a singular noun.

Answer (score 6):

*Policeman* is quite common in reference to male police officers, and I do not think I would even notice it. For that matter, the corresponding form *policewoman* is not uncommon. For example, here are some recent uses in *The New York Times*:

> Staring up at the steep and lifeless brown ridges looming over the valley, Gulzar Ahmad Dar, a boyish and chatty Kashmiri **policeman**, sighed at having drawn a short straw. [[link](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/13/world/asia/hikers-spread-democracy-in-india.html)]
>
> As soon as my passport was stamped, a **policewoman** strode over, said she had a text message for me and, though I laughed at her scam, requested a tip. [[link](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/19/magazine/jeffrey-wrights-gold-mine.html)]
>
> […] a woman from Canada who says a handful of French **policemen** raped her in Paris in April. [[link](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/25/travel/women-alert-to-travels-darker-side.html)]
>
> […] he said that Muslims who were responsible for vandalizing police vehicles, damaging public property and attacking **policewomen** during a rally in 2011 “will not be spared”. [[link](http://india.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/04/25/bharatiya-janata-partys-message-is-muddled-by-polarization/)]

As to whether this is “still sexist” — that seems very subjective to me, and depends greatly on the political and cultural context. You will need to decide for yourself how you feel about these usages.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is gender-exclusive, but that need not always lead us to recoil in utter horror. “Stewards must always offer any pregnant passenger assistance with *her* luggage” is also gender-exclusive, but I will personally undertake to assuage the hurt feelings of any pregnant male passengers who feel affronted by the wording of this guideline.

Comment: Speaking as a fisherperson, . . .

Comment: I was long ago an _angler,_ till I became a diver.

Answer (score 1):

Several people have suggested the use of the term "police officer" but we must be careful not to create confusion with non-human police actors such as dogs and AI systems.

To be specific, a police canine is often given an officer rank. If it is attacked or bitten that is treated as an offense against a serving office.

We need to say "a canine police officer" or a "human police officer" to clarify our specific case. This will grow more important as AI officers are deployed more widely.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_dog#United_States) says: "It is a felony to assault or kill a federal law enforcement animal, and it is a crime in most states to assault or kill a police animal. Yet despite common belief, police dogs are not treated as police officers for the purpose of the law, and attacking a police dog is not punishable in the same manner as attacking a police officer. Though many police departments formally swear dogs in as police officers, this swearing-in is purely honorary, and carries no legal significance."

Answer (score 0):

I recently read the word police used as a singular, non-gender specific noun. 
The author frequently wrote: "a police." 
See Laura Lippman, What the Dead Know.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Can you include some lines from the text you noted for context?  What kind of noun is in question, "the police" officer as a person vs "a police" as a police force?

Answer (score -2):

Another suggestion would be *police officer* as a more gender-neutral term.

Comment: Indeed. I note that the question itself uses the phrase *male police officer*.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer. Perhaps you could post it as a comment?

Comment: You are correct that 'police officer' is the term of the politically correct and policeman/policewoman are now considered retro and incorrect usage.

Answer (score -3):

There is no such thing as policewoman, firewoman, journeywoman, businesswoman.
It's a masculine noun so it is businessman, Foreman, fireman etc.
The word doesn't define the gender it defines the title. 
At work we never say forewoman. Yes she is a woman but the title is Forman because it's a masculine noun. 
 Another good example is with the French language. 
La= Feminine 
Le= masculine.

Comment: English does not have gendered nouns the way languages such as French do; I'm afraid your rationale is incorrect.