# Which one of this is the correct use of "one" as a pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> (a) When **one** reads the Hindi literature of the twentieth century, **he** finds a striking contrast between the writings of Munshi Premchand and later day writers of popular Hindi fiction.
>
> (b)  When **one** reads the Hindi literature of the twentieth century, **one** finds a striking contrast between the writings of Munshi Premchand and later day writers of popular Hindi fiction.

According to me, (b) should be the correct one as "one" cannot be used interchangeably with other pronouns when referring to the same thing.
But the correct answer is (a).
Can someone explain?

Comment: Related question, [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus). A question about gender-neutral **he** and **they** is one of the most popular questions in this community. You will find the link helpful.

Comment: Another related question, [Is using “he” for a gender-neutral third-person correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/is-using-he-for-a-gender-neutral-third-person-correct).

Comment: Who says that (a) is correct? I don't!

Comment: @WS2 You mean both are wrong?

Comment: Certainly (a) was used quite often before the movement to stop using *"he"* as a gender-neutral default pronoun. But I don't think (b) has ever been wrong. Consider [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+finds+oneself%2Cone+finds+himself&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20finds%20oneself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20finds%20himself%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Oscar Wilde: “When one is in town one amuses oneself. When one is in the country one amuses other people. It is excessively boring.”

Comment: @PeterShor But then it (option a) would be grammatically incorrect, won't it be?

Comment: c. When reading the Hindi literature of the twentieth century, one finds a striking contrast between the writings of Munshi Premchand and later day writers of popular Hindi fiction.

Comment: @Thinkeye: Sorry, that is not in the options.

Comment: @LucianSava: I do not understand your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a “correct” answer. There is no central authority in the English language that decides on the correctness of words or word usage. English is broadly spoken and adapted worldwide and has taken many words from other languages and from slang. The only rule in English is to try and write so that your readers will understand you.

You say that (a) is correct, but it is quite likely that somebody on the opposite side of the world from you is sitting in a classroom right now being taught that (b) is correct.

And here in the United States, if you use either (a) or (b) almost nobody will understand you. We would say:

> When you read the Hindi literature of the twentieth century, you find
>   a striking contrast between the writings of Munshi Premchand and later
>   day writers of popular Hindi fiction.

Comment: Although neither (a) nor (b) may be the most common formulation of this sentence in the U.S., I think "almost nobody will understand you" is a major overstatement.