# Is the grammar in this quote correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, quotes

This quote from Zig Ziglar doesn't seem right to me. I'm not sure if it's the **original** quote by him but is it grammatically correct?

> *One can get anything if he is willing to help enough others get what they want.*

I'm wondering about the use of 'one' and 'he' to refer to the same person, and 'help enough others' doesn't seem right to me either.

Comment: OK I done fixed it

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, is the part you're wondering about the use of "one" and "he" to refer to the same person? If so, the following question seems similar; you may find its answer helpful: [Which one of this is the correct use of “one” as a pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298663)

Comment: Yes, and 'help enough others' doesn't seem right to me either

Comment: "You can have everything in life you want, if you will just help other people get what they want" --a Zigler quote that is grammatical.
From: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/z/zigziglar381984.html

Comment: *Help enough others* is fine: *enough* qualifies *others* = "sufficient other people*.