# Which pronoun should be used with "anyone"? "They" or "you"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, singular-they

Sample sentence: If anyone has the files, could (*they* or *you*) please upload them to a file-hosting website?

Context: I am writing an email to a group of people requesting that if anyone has the files I mentioned, to please upload those files to a file-hosting website. "Anyone" could be one person or more.

Comment: Why not just avoid the issue and say: "Anyone who has the files, please upload them to a file-hosting website." Or even simpler, "If you have the files, please upload them to a file-hosting website."

Comment: "They".  Not "you".  Nothing second-person about "anyone".

Comment: @David: Yes, but by ellipsis, *If anyone has the files, [and if *you* are such a one,] could you please...*. You might say that's post factum justification, but many people do use *you* in OP's context.

Comment: Several questions like this have been closed as duplicates of [question #192](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her), which has answers that essentially answer the current question.  But also see [question #26721](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/anyone-they-or-he-she-why-is-it-sometimes-plural) or [question #59005](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59005/their-or-his-her) or [question #14331](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14331/use-of-they-as-singular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely, my first choice out of your dilemma would be to change the sentence slightly and write *"if anyone has the files, **please upload** them to a file-hosting website"*.

Otherwise, although I feel that *they* would be the right pronoun to use to refer to *anyone*, because you don't know how many people could have the file and also because you don't know whether these people are men or women, still I would write *you* in the sentence you mention, because the context is rather friendly and *they* might be interpreted as overly rigid and formal.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong with *they*. As the OED tells us, *they* is ‘often used in reference to a singular noun made universal by *every, any, no*, etc.’ It was good enough for, among others, Henry Fielding, Lord Chesterfield, Walter Bagehot and John Ruskin – and indeed is for most native speakers of English today.