# their or his/her

Tags: british-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it correct to use “their” instead of “his or her”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her)

Often I seen some write wrote "their" and some using "his/her". Which is correct?

Everyone has their weaknesses.

or

Everyone has his or her weaknesses.