# Why is "How are you" but not "How is You" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

My English is not very good. I just want to ask this simple question:

"These are","this is", "those are", "that is" means "are" is used for plural, but when asking to someone how is he, why people use "are': "how are you" instead of "how is you"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: *you* can be either plural or singular *semantically*, but *grammatically* it is always plural. ([The same is true of *they*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/208/300))

This is not unusual at all if you look at other languages. The semantically singular second-person *you* is grammatically:

- a third-person plural in German
- a third-person singular in Spanish
- a second-person plural in Russian

In English, *you* originally was a second-person plural. For the singular *you*, there was a different word: *thou* (cf. German *Du*, Spanish *tu*, Russian *ты*). So you would ask "how are you", but "how is thou" (more accurately, "how art thou", but that is going too deep). However, by now *thou* is obsolete and archaic. *You* [has taken over](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you).

Comment: This is true, but I don't think it is actually what the OP was asking about. (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 2):

The same personal pronoun rule is followed in both statements and questions:

- I **am** happy
- You **are** happy
- He **is** happy

*How are you?* just follows the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Because in *this is* etc, *this* (*these*, *that*, *those*) is syntactically the subject, so the verb agrees with it.

In *How are you?*, *how* is not a noun phrase, and so cannot function as subject. The sentence is inverted (as is usual in questions in English), and the subject is *you*, following the verb.

Compare *What do you want?*, where *what* is not the subject, so the verb *do* agrees with the subject *you*, which follows it.