# "May those hoping to enjoy their future waste none of their present." Correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, imperatives

Is that sentence correct, or would "future" and "present" need to become plural ("futures" and "presents")?

Those as plurals sound weird to me.

If my original sentence isn't grammatically correct, what would be an acceptable way of saying what I'm trying to say?

I also want to avoid clunky phrases such as "his or her".

Comment: It sounds fine to my ear the way you wrote it -- cf. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her

Comment: I personally like the way you wrote it in the title. I don't have a problem with the word futures, but presents sounds very strange, and similar to _presence_. I think it's especially fine considering you're using those and their for the sake of gender neutrality (I'm assuming).

Comment: presents makes me think of gifts.

Comment: I would just put a comma after *future* because without one I read *future waste* as a noun phrase meaning “waste that will be encountered in the future”  and then the rest of the sentence falls apart and must be reparsed from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like a revision that has "futures" and "presents."  While I don't like to fall back on the comment that "it doesn't sound right," here it really doesn't.

What about this:

"May those hoping to enjoy the future waste none of the present."

What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, that was a moment of confusion -- I don't know why I got the word wrong.  I've corrected it.

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion (definitely worth considering).  I do like the *personal* aspect of my original version though.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this page](https://writingtips.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/possessive-with-two-nouns/) (`New York’s and Chicago’s transportation systems`), the correct sentence would be:

> May those hoping to enjoy their futures waste none of their presents.

Futures and presents are indeed words. It may be debatable whether or not to use the plural versions, especially if the people in the sentence share a present and a future.

[Quick and dirty tip about it here.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-possession)

Comment: Could you say what on that linked page leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: That page is specifically talking about **two nouns**, or more specifically, several separate possessors coordinated by _and_. In the question here, we’ve got “those”, which is a single possessor, albeit a plural one, which is an entirely different situation.

Comment: [Those is plural.]( http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/This_That_These_Those.htm ) Therefore, there are multiple nouns that control their own futures

Comment: Ignore the formatting issue. Mobile. :/

Comment: I fail to see how saying "Bob's and Sarah's..." is different than "Our..." or "Their..."

Comment: Well, they are different, for whatever reason. When you have two nouns with just one possessive clitic and a singular possessee, it is unambiguous (in most cases) that the two nouns own the possessee in unison. With a pronoun, that is not the case. It is not possible to tell whether plural pronominal possessor + singular possessee denotes that all members of the possessor own just one possessee in unison, or that each of them owns one possessee. Similarly, a plural possessee may indicate individual (or plural) singular possessees or plural, unitedly owned possessees. It’s inherently ambiguous.

Comment: That's why we would say singular future if they owned it in unison. Plural  presents has to be owned individually. My friend and I cannot have multiple presents; it's illogical. You are correct about the ambiguity in a general sense, but in this case, it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Thus: “Bob and John’s wife” = B&J are both married to the same woman. “B&J’s wives” = B&J are unitedly married to several women _or_ separately married to one or more women. “B’s & J’s wife” = B&J are separately married to the same woman _or_ one woman each. “B’s & J’s wives” = B&J are both married to several women. “Some men see their wife as…” = these men are unitedly married to one woman _or_ separately to one woman each. “Some men see their wives as…” = they are unitedly married to the same women _or_ separately to one woman each _or_ separately to several women each.

Comment: your "B's&J's wife" and "B&J's wives" examples are wrong. the former defies logic (see answer's given example). the latter would rather be B&J unitedly marrying multiple women.