# Help understanding errors from English exam in Cyprus

Tags: possessives, errors

I had the following questions on an exam:

> SECTION 1: GENERAL ERRORS
>   The following sentences contain ONE grammatical or vocabulary error that has been underlined. Briefly explain why it is an error.
>
> Question 1: Jessica *boasted for* having won the first prize.
>   Question 2: The teacher wondered *where were the students* at the time.
>   Question 3: *The men* are sociable beings by nature.
>   Question 4: He has not yet gone to *the bed*.
>   Question 5: His *room's windows* are open.
>   Question 6: It is *everybody's* duty to defend *their* country.

I understand the issues with questions 1-4, but why are the words/phrases in italics in questions 5 and 6 considered as an error?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the source of your information claiming that there are errors in these sentences.

Comment: SECTION 1: GENERAL ERRORS
The following sentences contain ONE grammatical or vocabulary error that has been underlined. Briefly explain why it is an error.
Question 1:
Jessica boasted for having won the first prize.
Question 2:
The teacher wondered where were the students at the time.
Question 3:
The men are sociable beings by nature.
Question 4:
He has not yet gone to the bed.
Question 5:
His room's windows are open.
Question 6:
It is everybody's duty to defend their country

Comment: Thanks. The first four are clearly ungrammatical. But the ones you cite in your question are more controversial. Have a look at this question about the possessives of inanimate objects: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna. And this one about the singlar they:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either sentence. Rooms have windows. And singular they is fine in all but the most formal contexts.

Comment: Clare, that's what I thought. But this is a question in an exam in Cyprus!

Answer (score 2):

The second question is incorrect because everybody is ALWAYS singular. You must use his country (or his or her country).
The first sentence is awkward--why not just say The windows in his room?  Yet, technically, I don't consider it incorrect, but horribly worded.

Comment: @GlenPeterson Singular they is nothing new, it's rather the annoying prescriptivist peeves like "generic he" that are the annoying new kids on the block.

Comment: @dwight What do you mean with "everybody is ALWAYS negative"? Are you saying that you can not form positive sentences using _everybody_?

Comment: @GlenPeterson singular they/their is definitely not "historically wrong." There are several Q&A's (mostly the answers) that show its been used for hundreds of years. Just search the site, or the Internet,  for singular they.

Comment: The room's windows is rather unusual but not wrong. Strictly of course *everybody's* is always singular; that's why it's not *everybodies'*.

Most people won't even notice, let alone care if you use a plural singularity in a pub or a politically-correct council chamber but that doesn't mean it's a good idea in a language exam.

Comment: Thanks @oerkelens and Clare.  I learned something new!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they