# What are other forms of using the "people in general" pronoun, the equivalent of the French On?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which phrases (which are parallel to phrases in other languages, for example) would be correct and which not?

For example is it Ok to use "you can get x for free" when you refer to other people (when the person you are talking with is not looking for x but someone else is)?

Comment: The title of your question does not reflect its body. What are you **actually** asking for? Note that "is it ok?" questions are generally proofreading, which we don't do, and in this case you can look up *you,* find sense [A2 in Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you) and see that the use is fine. We consider English here and not other languages ([linguistics.se] **might** be the right place for that, but don't take my word for it). The "What other forms?" question of the title is less easy to look up and a valid question here, I think.

Comment: Of course, _one_ is the direct equivalent of the French _on_, but its use is rather more formal in English.

Comment: In certain contexts, ***you / one / we*** can use "we" instead of "one" to reference "anyone" as a non-specific "subject". People are really relaxed about such usages - in certain *other* contexts ***they*** might even use "they" the same way.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4110/is-it-more-appropriate-to-use-one-or-you-when-speaking-of-an-indefinite-pers

Comment: _One_ is the only permanently indefinite pronoun in English, though practically any pronoun (e.g, _you_) can be used in this sense. In addition, in U British speech, _one_ is used instead of first person - _One hardly knows what to say_ means "I'm speechless" in the right circles.

Comment: The French use of *on* is always used in a particular context. In addition to the pronouns, you/one/we or even they (Dans cette région, on ne parle pas comme ça.) In this region, they don't talk like that. It is also possible to have a passive construction: Mais, aux États-Unis , on ne dit pas ça. =That's not said in the States. **On ne peut pas séparer le pronom** de son contexte. The on pronoun **cannot be separated** from its context.

Answer (score 2):

There's no one pronoun that can translate *on*. Sometimes *you* works, and sometimes *we* works.

For your specific sentence, the only ways to say it are probably

> you can get x for free

or

> people can get x for free.

The sentence

> we can get x for free

suggests that we can get x, but not everybody can.

But sometimes *we* works and *you* doesn't. For example, in the sentence

> we don't know where elephants go to die

*we* works fine, but using *you* in that sentence might sugges that I know where the elephant graveyard is.

You can use *people* in both of those sentences, but I suspect *people* doesn't always work, either.

Comment: +1 And also sometimes *they* works too. *They don't know who shot JFK*, for example. And sometimes, so does *one*: *One doesn't want to intrude*, for example.