# How to take the gender of an anonymous person into consideration?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender, personal-pronouns, singular-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gender neutral pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun)

Very often, I find myself writing about *a user*, an anonymous person whose gender I don't know.

Right after mentioning this abstract user, I need to make a reference to the said person, and I often end up using *he/she*, as a shorter version of *he or she*.

Example:

> Note that the user may get confused by
>   the fact that green button turns red
>   when he/she presses the blue button.

And then I need to make another reference in another sentence right after that, and I find it heavy to write *he/she* again... So I write *he*.

I am confused by this because in French, every single noun has a gender. We don't have any neuter. *Utilisateur*, which means user in French, is masculine. Whereas *personne* is feminine.

So I don't have this problem in French. If I talk about *a user* then I can say *he*. If I talk about *a person*, I say *she*.

But how to deal properly and elegantly with this situation in English?

Is it acceptable to say *he*, as when one says *man* while talking about both men and women in general?

Comment: @MrHen: thanks for this pointer! But I think that you should mention this link in an answer to my question, as it may well be the right one.

Comment: Actually, we'll probably go ahead and close this question to keep all the answers in the same place. We're waiting for a few other opinions from users just to make sure.

Comment: @MrHen: ok, I hope that my question will still be useful to some people searching for this topic.

Comment: Probably. That is why we close and forward instead of deleting it. :)

Comment: @MrHen: That's nice :) And thanks for the pointer, it contains great and interesting answers!