# What are the most popular gender-neutral pronouns that aren't the same as other contemporary pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, singular-they, gender-neutral, generic-they

There have been attempts to use other contemporary English pronouns to stand-in as a true gender-neutral pronoun, given that English is lacking a commonly-accepted one for adult humans (non-humans and even babies can be referred to as 'it').  Examples of this include 'he/she', 'one', and the singular 'they'.

However, these can be confused with the contemporary pronouns which have been used as stand-ins, and they can at times be awkward to use.  Other pronouns exist which can avoid this problem, such as '**thon**', which seems to have historically picked up the most momentum, and was in the dictionary [as recently as 1964](http://illinois.edu/db/view/25/31097)!

Which are the most commonly used gender-neutral pronouns in English around the world today, to be used when referring back to an adult human, that aren't the same as other contemporary pronouns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gender neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun)

Comment: This is not a dupe.  That question is talking about a very specific choice between two pronouns.

Comment: @Jez: I disagree. But even if it isn't a dupe, than it should be closed for other reasons. If you are curious about _thon_, ask a question about _thon_.

Comment: 'thon' was an example.  This question is clearly about gender-neutral pronouns in general.

Comment: This question seems OK, since is about actual usage, not of the type "what words could you make up for x?". I am assuming that at least some people use these words, if only jokingly—or this question would be too localized. For now, I will vote to reopen if it should get closed.

Comment: @Jez: The question linked is about gender neutral pronouns in general; the answers there would be the same answers to this question.

Comment: @MrHen No.  I disagree.  It asks which one the person asking should use (including the standard he/she, it, singular they, etc. hacks) whereas mine asks which of the non-hacks are most popular.  They are different questions.

Comment: @Jez: The question you think you are asking is not the question in the title/body. Really, a few simple edits could fix this entire problem.

Comment: Question edited to be more unique.

Comment: @Jez: Good job! Voted to reopen and downvote removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Ze* and *hir*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ze_(pronoun)) have been around for some time, although they haven't gained much traction in the [cis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisgender) community. There're more listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun#Modern_solutions

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "ze" and "hir". I've often seen "ze" and "hir" used to refer to a particular person who's genderqueer/non-binary. Are these pronouns also used to refer to some generic/hypothetical person whose gender could be anything?

Answer (score 13):

There are no such pronouns in common use in any major dialect of English, though that's not for lack of trying. Since at least the 1850s, various linguistic do-gooders have proposed more than 80 potential gender-neutral pronouns, none of which ever gained traction. [A sampling](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/750/is-there-a-gender-neutral-substitute-for-his-or-her):

> thon, thons; ne, nis, nim; hi, hes, hem; e, es, em; ir, iro, im; ip, ips; he'er, him'er, his'er, his'er's; te, tes, tir; shis, shims, shim, shimself; zie , zees, zim, zeeself; per, pers

All of these have the significant drawback of being ridiculous, which is probably the reason singular *they* is the only option that's come close to mainstream acceptance. Until the prescriptivists accept singular *they*, we're stuck with rewriting to eliminate the gender-specific pronoun.

Comment: Voted you down because of your random subjective assertion that these proposals are 'ridiculous'.  I think several of them would work just fine.

Comment: @Jez: The subjective assertion is a problem with how you asked the question.

Comment: Elaborate.  I don't see how the asking of the question is a problem (seriously.)

Comment: @Jez: Sadly your question is to subjective, and also the 'ridiculous' part of the answer (despite the fact that I agree with the entire sentiment of the answer). Substitute 'ridiculous' with the slightly more objective 'difficult to  recognize as English'.

Comment: How is the question too subjective?  I'm asking which pronouns are common in English today; this is looking for a purely factual answer.

Comment: @phenry I'll accept this as the answer if you change the 'being ridiculous' to something like 'seeming somewhat unusual to a native English speaker'.

Comment: +1 "Somewhat unusual" would be misleading to beginner ESL students, who might actually use one of these words. Many people, including me, will at least chuckle if decorum permits; this would seem to warrant "ridiculous"—though perhaps *jocular* would provide a friendlier perspective.

Comment: @Cerberus Still, it would be nice if one of them became widely used!  English could do with such a word.

Comment: @Jez: Well... perhaps so! You're right that the pronouns we have now appear to be problematic to a substantial group; but it's just not the kind of linguistic change I'd personally want to lead. (By the way, I think the traditional pronouns may continue to serve us as well as they always have, if feminists decide that changing language isn't really necessary or effective in changing society...)

Comment: @Cerberus They don't serve well for referring to people of uncertain gender, like that South African person recently in the news because they weren't sure if *thon* was a woman.  :-)

Comment: @Jez: Heh, I missed that, but I will admit that there are some situations in which *he/she* won't do. But then we have the ugly *a/the/this person* as a last resort. In cases like *we ask each student to deliver his key to the dean's office*, traditional English has no problem with *his* to refer to both men and women.

Comment: @Cerberus Nope, but I just prefer *thons*.  ;-)  It sounds right, like it could be a Germanic word (not something wacky like zee).  I can get used to saying it very easily.  And it would make English more awesome if it didn't have this shortcoming.

Comment: @Jez: While you're at it, why don't you also make up a word that would work in all Indo-European languages? I don't think any of them have such a word! (English just seems to be the only language where this is felt to be a problem. In Dutch, the masculine/neuter pronouns are used with any unknown gender, though the occasional complaint may be heard now and then.)

Comment: @Cerberus Surely different words would be appropriate for different Indo-European languages.  *Thon* may sound nice to an English speaker's ear, but I doubt it would to a Spanish or Italian speaker's.  Likewise, *zee* sounds like it'd fit in much more nicely with Dutch or German to me.