# Gender question

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender, singular-they, political-correctness, generic-they

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Speaking about someone of unknown gender…](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28890/speaking-about-someone-of-unknown-gender)
>   [Gender neutral pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun)

I'm writing a paper about markets and mention several times providers and their offers. The problem is when I use the singular, since I'm not sure if I should use a male or female pronouns. For example, is it a provider and **his** offer or a provider and **her** offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just as well use "a provider and **their** offer" to keep it neutral and still in the singular person.

Comment: Is that even gramatically correct? Can I use **their** when I write in singular?

Comment: @Ivan: Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they for more

Comment: @Ivan: yes, it is, and yes, you can. See [Is it correct to use “their” instead of “his or her”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her), in addition to the [Gender neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun) question linked above.

Answer (score 1):

The generic pronoun, is "he"  and [is defined:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/he?o=100074)

> anyone (without reference to sex); that person:

"He" has been used as a generic pronoun for some time, and will be understood.

I would advise you to use "he", or "his", or "him", when referring to anyone in general.

However, due to feminist movements in recent times, if you want to be absolutely [politically correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness), then you would substitute words like "one" i.e. A manager should know one's duties, or usage of the neuter pronoun "they" and "their", as in:

> Sportspersons should know their limits in actions. They should be able to discern what is acceptable, and what is not.