# Was "man" a gender-neutral word in common usage at some point?

Tags: historical-change, grammatical-gender

I've seen some times the claim that in the past "man" was a non-gendered word, with "wifman" referring to female individuals and "wereman" referring to male individuals. I've found some indications that "wifman" was either a predecessor or a complement to "woman", and even the root for the current "wife". I've failed to find solid information regarding "man" being a truly neutral word (and not just a masculine word applied to both female and male individuals) and "wereman" or any alternative being the default word for male individuals.

So, **was "man" a non-gendered word in the English language or its predecessors at some point, with different words derived from it (as woman is today) to refer to both male and female individuals?**

Note: My main language is entirely gendered, and we have no way to address someone in a gender-neutral way that is common usage. If anything comes across as rude, please say so and I'll correct it. I understand this may be a sensitive topic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103318/discussion-on-question-by-lordhieros-was-man-a-gender-neutral-word-in-common-u).

Comment: Of possible related interest: *[Can “man” always be used to mean both men and women?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44991/)*, *[Gender-neutral alternative to “craftsmanship”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/205284/16052)*, *[Is “man” as in “mankind” to refer to humans considered sexist now?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450029/)* and others.

Comment: @LordHieros: If you are interested only in the distant past, in which *wifman* and *wereman* were used, it would be a good idea to make that clearer, and in particular to make it explicit in the title of the question. The current wording of the question and its title will keep attracting a lot of people who are interested in the debates about the use of *man* at present and in the recent past.

Comment: @jsw29 I wanted a comprehensive answer, not just limited to a time period, which is why I did not specify strictly distant past; if I knew exactly the usage of the term I wouldn't have needed to ask. I think Taliesin gives a great overview to the question as posed, and wouldn't want to alter it fundamentally after a good answer already exists

Comment: @LordHieros, the accepted answer **is** about Old English. That very illuminating answer carefully avoids getting into the controversial issues about the more recent and current use of *man*. The other contributors to this page are, however, interested precisely in discussing these controversial issues, and the title of the question is likely to attract more of such discussion.

Comment: John McWhorter recently did an entertaining podcast about this subject: https://slate.com/podcasts/lexicon-valley/2019/11/irregular-plurals-in-the-english-language

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Man** in Old English could be either gendered or non-gendered. We inherited that ambiguity.

In Old English, **man** referred to both an adult male and a human being of either sex. Here is Stephen A. Barney in *Word-Hoard: An Introduction to Old English Vocabulary*, entry 8:

> **Mann** serves for both "adult male" and "human being (of either sex)," in English; the other Germanic langs. adopted distinct words for the two senses: ModG **Mann** and **Mensch** "human being." The latter form occurs in OE (not in our texts) as **mennisc** (adj.) "human(s)," which survived to the 12th c. The OE terms which discriminate sexes are **wer** (Lat. **vir**) and **wif** (+ man = **woman**). ModG, like OE, has **man** in nom. (unstressed) meaning "one" (cf. French **on**).

Compounds include an early version of mankind, *man-cynn*. So what we have is a word that can refer to either adult males or human beings. Furthermore, it was sometimes hard to distinguish these uses. While the context makes telling them apart easily enough in this usage [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/113198):

> lOE   Anglo-Saxon Chron. (Laud) anno 639   Þæs dohter wæs gehaten Ercongota halifemne, & wundorlic **man**. (This daughter was called Eorcengota holywoman and wonderful **man**)

Can you tell which *man* is meant in the next two uses? *Testicles* makes the second **men** obvious. The first **manne** (referring to [men being hanged for thievery](http://mcllibrary.org/Anglo/part7.html)) is rather harder, unless you believe that only men could be hanged for thievery.

> lOE   Anglo-Saxon Chron. (Laud) (Peterborough contin.) anno 1124   Þet wæron on þa litle hwile ealles feower & feowerti **manne**, & six **men** spilde of here ægon & of here stanes. (There were in a little while four and forty **men*, and six **men** spoiled of their eyes and their testicles.)

Or how about the following usage? In the Old English Homilies, did Jesus became both **man** (an adult male) or **man** (a human being) for us? Either fits.

> a1200   MS Trin. Cambr. in R. Morris Old Eng. Homilies (1873) 2nd Ser. 199 (MED)   He bi-com **man** for us.

Also, to the extent we've been discussing a word in a language that still had grammatical gender, *man* in Old English is masculine. While grammatical gender should not be confused with biological gender (see Latin *poeta*, *agricola*, *incola*, *nauta*, all appear feminine in form but function masculine when modified by adjectives and most likely refer to men), grammatical gender doesn't help us distinguish semantically gender-neutral cases here.

So it would oversimplify to calling this usage *gender-neutral* OR strictly *gendered*, since the reading as *adult male* and the reading as *human being* may lead to ambiguity. Furthermore, such ambiguity doesn't exist for any word that refers to women - **wif**, **bryd**, **faemne**, **cwene**, and other words for women do not enjoy double-status as words referring to humans in general. Thus, while Old English **man** could be used to refer to human beings (including individual women), **man** (and the adult male it sometimes refers to) possesses a dual quality that **woman** and other female terms lack.

Comment: Indeed: the 1662 Prayer Book version of the Nicene Creed has "...who for us men, and for our salvation..." and that definitely does not exclude half the human race.

Comment: I find this anwswer really comprehensive, and highlighting what I'd missed: that usage of the word man in a non-gendered and gendered way is undistinguishable in most cases. Plus, since nowadays we still can refer to humanity as mankind, I guess it's a bit of a moot point. I'll be accepting this answer after the 24h courtesy period, most likely.

Comment: @LordHieros For bonus points, "girl" used to mean young person, and "boy" used to mean servant (though _usually_ male). And it's much the same for the so-called male pronoun, "he" - it's already the gender-neutral pronoun, there's no need for some "they" or such. Even "she" doesn't necessarily mean a female - it's also used as an affectionate pronoun for all sort of subjects. In the end, gender distinction just doesn't matter most of the time, so it's not weird language doesn't reflect it much (even in gendered languages). And our son used to call us both "mama", regardless of gender :)

Comment: Adding to this:  apparently "wereman"/"wærman" was supplanted by just "man" [in the 1300s](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=man).  (This actually has interesting conjugations with marriage ceremonies:  traditionally the pronouncement was as "man and wife" - or, earlier than that, as "wer and wif" - rather than "husband and wife", because "husband" (from the Norse "hus-bondi" meaning "house owner") *also* wasn't gendered.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: ["And they that had eaten were about five thousand men, beside women and children."](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+14%3A13-21&version=KJV) Matthew 14:13-21

Comment: This is a remarkably good answer, except I find the term "linguistic privilege" in your last sentence a bit odd and confusing rather than clarifying.

Comment: @EricDuminil assuming that is what the original Greek means, how else would you propose to translate it? ("Adults self-identifying as male" sounds like a quote from a police report...) Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar. And most common words have many more than one sense defined in dictionaries.

Comment: Regarding Jesus being **"_made man_"**, that's generally a reference to Jesus gaining human form -- ambiguously at either conception or birth.  This seems incompatible with the adult-male interpretation.

Comment: "unless you believe that only men could be hanged for thievery." <- It is not hard to believe that in a society where women are not treated equally, their criminal liability is also limited, and thus would not be hanged for thievery; or that women in such a society would tend not to engage in grand thievery as opposed to petty theft.

Comment: As a side note: _poeta, agricola, incola, nauta, ..._ **are** grammatically masculine in Latin (adjectives that modify them take masculine forms), they just have a declension pattern used mostly for feminine nouns.

Comment: In french there is a version of man which comes from the latin for hand and gives words line manual labour, mano a mano(spanish), manutention(french).

Comment: @einpoklum: They were treated differently throughout most of history, but for much of history, they were executed (just less often) just the same. Not the same time period (records of common criminal executions generally not surviving from the semi-literate, minimal rule of law period in which Old English was spoken), but they [hanged a few hundred women (out of over a thousand sentenced) in the mid-late 18th century, some of them for robbery or thievery](https://www.capitalpunishmentuk.org/fem1735.html), which was hardly a period of gender equality.

Comment: Not to mention more modern usage as "One small step for a man, one giant leap for mankind."  Here Armstrong rather poetically contrasted his individual self ("a man") and all humans ("mankind"). It would be a stretch to suggest he was only talking about adult males!

Comment: @EricDuminil The King James Bible was written in 1611 after the word man clearly derived its double meaning.  This question I believe is more about its use in middle and old English (~1450 and earlier).

Answer (score 29):

I'm old enough to remember when "man" or the combining for "-man" was just common usage. "All men are created equal" was just taken for granted as meaning "All persons were created equal." Words like spokesman, craftsman, chairman, etc. were easy to use and didn't raise any gender questions.

Of course "man" could also be used in a strictly male sense. "Be a man, my son." "This is a job for a strong man." etc.

So you have a word which COULD be gender-specific or COULD be used otherwise. Languages aren't always consistent.

Comment: _Man_ has not been gender-neutral within the lifespan of anyone currently alive. The plural, _men_, is a different story, but singular _man_ is only (possibly) gender-neutral as a suffix. “There’s a man at the door” is quite unambiguously gendered in Modern English (and was probably even heavily skewed towards genderedness even in Old English). [The non-count use is also a different matter, of course, referring to mankind in general.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103508/discussion-on-answer-by-catlest-was-man-a-gender-neutral-word-in-common-usage).

Answer (score 23):

Yes.  From the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www-oed-com.proxy.lib.ohio-state.edu/view/Entry/113198?rskey=DLIUN9&result=1#eid) (subscription required):

> *Man* was considered until the 20th cent. to include women by implication, though referring primarily to males. It is now frequently understood to exclude women, and is therefore avoided by many people.

and then, before beginning its selection of quotations, remarks

> In some of the quotations in this section, it is difficult or impossible to tell whether *man* is intended to mean ‘person’ or ‘male human being’.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103509/discussion-on-answer-by-gedgar-was-man-a-gender-neutral-word-in-common-usage-a).

Answer (score 8):

There have been many historical uses of **man** to mean all people well into the 20th century as well. In 1942, Disney released Bambi [which has this line](http://moviescript.yolasite.com/bambi.php)

> BAMBI: What happened mother? Why did we all run?
>
> BAMBI'S MOTHER: Man was in the forest

Time Magazine had a long running tradition of naming a [Man of the Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Person_of_the_Year) (*Person of the Year* since 1999). While women named were *Woman of the Year*, when they would name a group of people, that group would be *Man of the Year*. [1967 featured Baby Boomers](https://time.com/4607270/1967-january-6-anniversary/)

[image]

In 1962, the Twilight Zone had one of its most famous episodes, [To Serve Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_(The_Twilight_Zone)), in which aliens come with vast knowledge, ostensibly to help all mankind. The title, however,

> is a bit of a pun. "To Serve Man", a book the aliens have, is not how to help mankind, but how to best cook the people they take back to their planet.

Answer (score 8):

The 1662 [A Brief and Easie Explanation of the Shorter Catechism](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnhnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22man%20both%20male%20and%20female%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX7PPV3IrnAhUl11kKHfzWDHQQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22man%20both%20male%20and%20female%22&f=false) says:

> Q.[...] Did God create man both Male, and Female, after his own Image?
>   ...
>   A. God created Man, Male and Female, after his own Image ...

The 1674 [The Body of Divinity, Or, a Confession of Faith](https://books.google.com/books?id=LVFnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22man%22%20%22both%20male%20and%20female%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD4IaCw4jnAhUH2FkKHStFCP8Q6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22man%22%20%22both%20male%20and%20female%22&f=false) says:

> God made man *in his own image, male and female he created them*. He created Man both Male and Female ;  for by the word Man, is intended Mankind, *i. e.* both Man and Woman.

Comment: Nice quote, but it does seem that the author then felt compelled to clarify straightaway that by Man they meant mankind and inclusive of both Man and Woman

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't think he is clarifying inclusiveness of Man and Woman, since the words used are 'Male' and 'Female'. What is being stated, is that He created Man in two forms.

Comment: @GlenYates did you click through and read the full quote? "He created Man both Male and Female; for by the word man is intended mankind; i.e. both Man and Woman". Definitely sounds like he is clarifying what is meant by the term there

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and by far the most famous example of this recent change is, of course:

In "old" Star Trek

> ## "To boldly go where no man has gone before"

and in new Star Trek

> ## "To boldly go where no one has gone before"

This is a fascinating question.

For anyone born before, oh, 1980 the answer to the title question

> Was “man” a gender-neutral word in common usage at some point?

is ... "yes, of course, obviously."

**BUT** for folks born after about 1980 (?), it's a question!

---

Another exceedingly famous example of the "old" usage is, of course, one of the most famous utterances in English, and, the first utterance ever, off-world:

> ## "One small step for man..."

So that was July 20, 1969.  That year, it was utterly universal to use 'man' as 'human'.

Don't even mention "mankind" which is also on the way out these days.

Comment: See https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/is-neil-armstrongs-famous-moon-landing-quote-really-a-misquote-524458 'As the American astronaut himself pointed out many times, the sentence is meaningful only if he says, "That's one small step for **a** man."'

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Early Old English, "man" was used to refer to a human, without respect to sex. After Old English, the usage of the gender-neutral definition was restricted to to refer to a generic humans or humans in general. Starting around 1000 (which is during Old English), "man" was also used refer to a male human, so it would have been used in a purely gender-neutral way only before then. Using "man" to refer to humans without respect to gender started falling out of favor in the late 20th century, due to the influence of feminism.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=man) comments:

> Specific sense of "adult male of the human race" (distinguished from a woman or boy) is by late Old English (c. 1000);

implying that "man" was used in a purely non-gendered way before then.

Indeed, OED's quotations for the definition of "a human being as a designation applied equally to particular individuals of either sex" are earlier than the ones for the definition referring to male humans. (eOE, Early Old English, is considered to be from 600–950.)

> eOE   Leechbk. (Royal) (1865) iii. xxxviii. 332   Gif wife to swiþe offlowe sio monað gecynd, genim niwe horses tord, lege on hate gleda, læt reocan swiþe betweoh þa þeoh up under þæt hrægl, þæt se **mon** swæte swiþe.

In contrast, the earliest quotation for the definition "a male human" is circa 1000:

> OE   Ælfric Lives of Saints (Julius) (1881) I. 28   He..sæde hyre gewislice hwæt heo **man** ne wæs.

Etymonline continues:

> Old English used wer and wif to distinguish the sexes, but wer began to disappear late 13c. and was replaced by man. Universal sense of the word remains in mankind and manslaughter. Similarly, Latin had homo "human being" and vir "adult male human being," but they merged in Vulgar Latin, with homo extended to both senses.
>
> Man also was in Old English as an indefinite pronoun, "one, people, they." It was used generically for "the human race, mankind" by c. 1200. As a word of familiar address, originally often implying impatience, c.1400; hence probably its use as an interjection of surprise or emphasis, since Middle English but especially popular from early 20c.

Oxford English Dictionary comments:

> A human being (irrespective of sex or age).
> Man was considered until the 20th cent. to include women by implication, though referring primarily to males.

The last quotation for the non-gendered sense of "man" (and not "men") referring to a specific individual is also from Old English:

> Ælfric's Homily De Initio Creaturae (Vesp. A.xxii) in R. Morris Old Eng. Homilies (1868) 1st Ser. 223   He com þa anedren hiwe toðam twam **mannum**, erest toðan wife.

But the usage of "man" and "men" to refer to a generic human or humans in general, irrespective of gender, continued well into the 20th century.

"Woman", meaning "an adult female human being", appears in Early Old English as "wifmon", as seen in the OED's quotation here:

> eOE   tr. Orosius Hist. (BL Add.) (1980) iii. vi. 60   Minutia hatte an **wifmon** þe on heora wisan sceolde nunne beon [L. Minucia uirgo Vestalis].

Thus, it is true that the "man" in "woman" is non-gendered, at least at the word was created.

As an aside, some other answers consider a word with both a gendered and non-gendered meaning, but primarily a gendered meaning, to be a gender-neutral word, which I find odd.