# Generic way for writing about person without knowing his/her gender

Tags: grammatical-gender, singular-they, gender-neutral, generic-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Is there generic way to write something like this

```
Karin Bellow replied to his own post.
```

But making this sentence generic, because writing `his` I suppose that I write to male person.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would write *Karin Bellow is replying to **their** own post*.  Using *they* when gender is unspecified or unknown has a long and honorable tradition.

Comment: Their is plural and Karin is singular. I don't think this is a good resolution. There is not a pronoun for people that does not refer to gender.

Comment: "They" is morphologically and syntactically plural. However, it is semantically either singular or plural depending on usage. Here it is being used as a semantic singular.

Comment: @Barbara  Singular *they* is widely used and understood, and in this context it is not inappropriate.  All the alternatives (*he / she*, *he*, *she* or *it*) have problems.

Comment: I like using singular **they**, but I find it confusing when applied to people with names.

Comment: @PeterShor Then write "Karin's".