# "Layman" and gender equality

Tags: grammar, grammatical-gender

Is it correct to write:

> He wants to explain *X concept* to the layman, not before warning *him* ...

Or should I write:

> He wants to explain *X concept* to the layman, not before warning *him* or *her* ...

Comment: Why not 'layperson'?

Comment: You can use *layperson* if you want to appear politically correct or gender-neutral.

Comment: Obviously your first suggestion is entirely correct. The masculine includes the feminine and "him or her" is unnecessary. Unless you are insecure or wallowing in political correctness.

Comment: The title seems to be asking about the gender-neutrality of *layman*, while the body is asking for a gender-neutral pronoun. The latter is a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus). Please clarify what you're really after.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I like your suggestion. If I mean "non-expert" or "non-professional", is 'layperson' really common? So, the solution would be "He wants to explain X concept to the layperson, not before warning him" ...?

Comment: More common to say "He wants to explain X concept in layman terms..." The later construct "not before" overcomplicates the sentence, it might be better to rephrase that. Do you simply mean "after"?

Comment: Jorge, "He wants to explain X concept to the layperson, not before warning whom ..." is better.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: If it's for publication, it probably demands PC language. If it's informal, then I agree that it's "_wallowing_" in PC. An ngram shows a steep curve of _layperson_ usage from ca. 1975-1998, then an equally precipitous fall from 2001. "_Him or her_" peaked & fell at ca. the same time with twice the usage. We're conflicted about "_gender neutral_" nouns & pronouns. It's a small but real issue. When I was a kid, I didn't think that "_The masculine includes the feminine and 'him or her' is unnecessary_"; I thought "_The masculine excludes the feminine_". You're a reactionary. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke  He's not a reactionary; he's a conservative, who (we may suppose) is in the happy position of being able to employ whatever rule he is comfortable with. More power to him.

Comment: @StoneyB: He's a "reactionary" alright. He told me so himself and reaffirmed it after I said something about his being "retrograde". That's why I added the smiley face. "[I]n the happy position of being able to employ whatever rule he is comfortable with" is akin to being extra-social and a subjective idealist. But that's okay. As long as all the cards are on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy (and for once not inelegant) solution is to evade the issue by using the collective:

> He wants to explain *X* to the laity, not before warning them ...

EDIT
Since use of *laity* in a non-religious sense has excited considerable comment, I note that *OED 1* dates it back to 1832, citing the *Jurisprudence* of John Austin, a leading philosopher of law:

> The laity (or non-lawyer part of the community) are competent to conceive the more general rules.

And for those who object to grounding an argument on the usage of a lawyer, I offer the greatest modern master of English prose style:

> All professions are conspiracies against the laity. —Bernard Shaw, *Preface to The Doctor's Dilemma*

Comment: just to be clear, "laity" doesn't sould disrespectful, right?

Comment: That's right -- no more disrespectful than does "lay". "Laity" is the collective term for all lay persons; it is employed in the literal sense by religious writers (including those in the Church), and in the figurative sense wherever there is a clear distinction between experts and everybody else. If anything, disrespect is imputed in the **other** direction, when a writer wants to suggest that the experts take an inflated view of their status.

Comment: Right, it doesn't sound disrespectful, just a bit more religion-related. If it's not about the Church, then people sometimes use "_amateurs_" or "_civilians_", both fairly informal, or "_nonprofessionals_", more formal.

Comment: @BillFranke  In many fields, however, "amateur" is a term of distinct opprobrium. My impression is that "civilian" still has what the *OED* calls a *joc.* ring when not contrasted with the military.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this solution, not unless we're talking about a pastor. When I look up [layman](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/layman), I see a primary meaning that fits the context exactly; when I look up [laity](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/laity), that meaning is conspicuously absent. While I realize [some dictionaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laity) will list BOTH meanings under laity, the expression _in layman's terms_ is common, but _terms that the laity can understand_ sounds almost foreign to my US ear.

Comment: @J.R.: I agree. So only the pronoun is the problem.

Comment: To clarify, the topic `X` here stands for is about math and physics. I didn't know the answer would be that disputed, so I didn't specify the theme in the question.

Comment: @J.R.  It may not be common; but I Google "literary laity" and get 64 hits; and 3 of the first 10 are unambiguously in this sense. With "scientific laity" I get 1,840 hits; 10 of 10 are in this sense.

Comment: Language use is a bitch. Words seem not to matter to so many speakers & writers until some word pushes **their** buttons, & then the sky falls. Everything said & written in English these days is indisputably disputable & has been exceedingly so since the 1960s. We're told in biomed that we must say "_A patient with [disease X]_" rather than "_A [disease X] patient_" because the latter makes it sound as if [disease X] is a personal trait (e.g., "_a diabetic patient_") rather than a temporary state of being ("fisherman" vs. "fishing man" vs. "sleeping man"). Makes writing tough sometimes.

Comment: Putting things in terms ["a layman can understand"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+layman+can+understand%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), the problem is that version turns up 6,230 times in Google Books, but ["the laity can understand"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+laity+can+understand%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) their stuff only 287 times. I also think that *layman* today usually just means *nonprofessional*, whereas *laity* still tends to mean *lay people, as distinct from the clergy*.

Comment: @BillFranke: Haha, ridiculous. PC-ness sucks. Just refuse!

Comment: @Cerberus  Ridiculous, indeed; but no more, and no more onerous, than, say, conforming your punctuation to a house style. He who pays the piper calls the tune, and the lyrics, too.

Comment: StoneyB: For the record, I never doubted it was a valid use of the word (and even took care to link to a dictionary that supported you); I only meant to point out that what one might gain in political correctness could be easily offset by the relative rarity of the expression. As @Bill said in his comment to the O.P., it's a tradeoff, and the author would do well to consider the target audience before making a final decision.

Comment: @J.R.  Oh, I knew that. My feeling is that what you lose in familiarity you gain in panache.

Comment: @Cerberus: If we refuse, we're told to change the expression if we want to have the article published. It's publishing politics. I've never liked PC language, but I'm socially challenged. :-)

Comment: @StoneyB: The problem with PC-ness is that there is a world of misunderstanding and finger-pointing behind it, while a house style will at least admit that it is fairly arbitrary. But, yes, it too can be very annoying.

Comment: @BillFranke: Haha, I understand. But you are morally obliged to mutter and curse between your teeth! Preferably in un-PC terms.

Comment: I do, I do, I do, I do, I do! [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdRESyMPxDA)  (8-E

Comment: -1 for Bernard Shaw, who had distinctly peculiar views on English (including "standardising" spelling, losing apostrophes and even capital letters, odd spacing...)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Did you really downvote just because of Shaw? Or perhaps it was the labeling of Shaw as "the greatest modern master of English prose style" that prompted you to click the downvote button?  Either way, OUCH!  Like Shaw or hate him, I thought the quote was apt for the debate at hand.

Comment: This comment thread is now getting auto-flagged for its length. Everybody is reminded of our chat. Here, things that are not directly related to the answer will have to be deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either using *layperson* and using either *him or her* or *them* which can be used as a singular.

Historically, *he* can be used to mean *he or she*, but nowadays I think it's less acceptible due to changing tastes and English being a living, changing language. I've also seen *she* used meaning *he or she* and I think that's fine but inelegant.

I would use *he or she*/*him or her* or *they*/*them*.

The singular-they has been used in English for a long time, and I think ultimately offends fewer people than just *he* or just *she*.