# how to refer a person with undefined sex?

Tags: pronouns, translation, grammatical-gender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

The title is a little confused because I don't know how to explain in one line,  so:

I have a Portuguese phrase like this:

> Marque alguém como amigo(a). Ele(a) receberá uma notificação.

which literally translated to English means:

> Mark someone as friend. He(or she) will get notified.

In Portuguese, the “(a)” means the female version of the word. How can I do that in English?  Does this work:

> Mark someone as friend. He/she will get notified.