# more usage of their and they with any way

Tags: possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

I want to learn more usage of 'their' which is an possessive and in any way of 'they'.  You can see a few examples below. Are all those words correct usage in those sentences?

*to banish* : If someone is banished, **they** are punished by being sent away from the country where they live.

*to invade* : if someone or something invades your privacy **they** disturb you when you want to be alone.

When an actor completely immerses **themselves** into a role...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: Thanks for informing. I'll read the topic who has asked before me as similar and I hope it does work to get the meaning.