# How one refers to a third person without specifying the sex or number?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Is there a generalized way to do this.

Who is it used in modern media (internet, tv, movies, songs), in a colloqial context, (among family and friends), and in a formal environment (work office)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“[Singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)” (with its inflections) is the pronoun which is genderless and not necessarily singular or plural.

Comment: There's a statement that "However, “singular they” also enjoys a long history of criticism." (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/14666)

Comment: And what if I saw someone in a distance but I could not determine if it was a woman or a man? What should I say: `I saw a man.` or `I saw a woman.` or `I saw a person.` or maybe `I saw a figure.`?

Comment: @krokoziabla: You'd say "I saw a person," or "I saw someone." The _singular they_ might work like this: "I saw someone; they were jumping up and down."

Comment: @MrLister  "They" have [done so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun#Invented_pronouns), repeatedly, but none of the inventions has caught on yet. Hardly surprising, given that it took the better part of four hundred years for English to settle on the set we've got.