# Which pronoun should I use when writing about a generic activity in a thesis?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

I'm writing my Bachelor's thesis where I describe students' activities in a dormitory.

> A student produces with a valid ID or passport here and hands in an ID
>   card photo. In case he/she has a reserved room, there is prepared a
>   printed dormitory agreement.

Should I use only plural in the whole document or is singular form also applicable?

Comment: Welcome! I think this has appeared before: this is a possible duplicate of [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun ("his" versus "her" versus "their")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Comment: Replace "he/she" with "the student"; change "In case" to "If": _If the student has a reserved room..._. Also, remove the first "with": _A student produces a valid ID..._ To answer your questions: the singular is acceptable, but, as you've discovered, it can lead to some awkward pronoun-gender problems. Two solutions: (1) use "they" in place of "he/she"; or (2) use one or the other, and put a note at the front of your thesis that says that gender-specific pronouns are not meant to be restrictive, and are only used in place of the much uglier he/she or (s)he.

Comment: I have removed the second part of your question because it is a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/) and the many questions linked from there. On a more general note, Stack Exchange works best when questions are limited to one question, especially if the several questions are unrelated, as was the case here. Otherwise you can get a good answer that focuses on question one, an equally good answer that focuses on question two, etc. — and you have no idea which of them to mark as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for altering of the topic. I didn't know how to search for a similar topic, because I didn't know correct phrases and words. Also, thank you J.R. for pointing out some other things.

Comment: Question as it stands is a request for writing advice/critique and should be redirected to Writing.SE.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't want to seem dismissive, but it seems to me the *he/she* issue is the least of your problems with even these two sentences. If it's at all possible, I suggest you see if you can write your thesis in your native language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I could do it in my native language, but the thing is, I don't want to. My english is not so bad and I count on services of an english corrector.

Comment: @Andrew: Your English certainly isn't *so* bad, and I suppose you must have a good reason why you want to write the thesis in English. But it does seem to me that just gives you more things to worry about, when you probably want to concentrate on *what* you're saying, rather than *how* you say it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I have a good reason. And if I am writing it in my native language, I would still have to think about how to write it and then let a corrector to check it. So I'll take my chances here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singular, as you have used with *A student produces...* is not only possible but may be clearer than the plural. This is because with *Students produce...ID photos*, it would not be clear whether each student should produce one photograph or a set; *A student produces a photo* is unambiguous.

Whichever you choose, do check (repeatedly) that you remain consistent throughout the document.  If you start *Students produce their valid IDs* and later go on to *a dormitory agreement*, it would be reasonable to assume that only one agreement is produced per dormitory. Conversely, *A student arrives with a valid ID* which later mutates to *their passports* is arguably ungrammatical, and quite possibly confusing.

(Note to supporters of singular *their*; the word was 'arguably'. Your dictionary citations do not alter the fact that it is controversial , and therefore best avoided in a thesis written in your second language. Can we please not have this same argument every time the point is mentioned?)

Comment: "A student arrives with a valid ID which later mutates to their **passports**" is unarguably ungrammatical. For it to be grammatical, even for members of the singular _they/them/their_ cadre, it'd have to be "A student arrives with a valid ID which later mutates to their **passport**", unless each student has two or more passports, which would be probable only at 007 University.