# About adjective possessive pronouns

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

In the sentence ‘Everyone should make *everyone’s* part’, what adjective possessive pronoun should replace the word *everyone’s*?

Comment: Conventionally, *his*. Alternatively, *their*.

Comment: That's a very odd example usage. Did you perhaps mean [Everyone should **play** his part](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everyone+should+play+his+part%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)?

Comment: Valéria, you might be interested in our new proposal "Italian Language & Usage". Please, commit http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language-usage Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

"Everyone" is singular, so the following are all acceptable:

> Everyone should make his part.
>
> Everyone should make his or her part.
>
> Everyone should make her or his part.
>
> Everyone should make her part.
>
> Everyone should make their part.

"Her or his" or "her" would sometimes be used to combat male-positive gender bias.  "Her" or "his" might also be used in a non-offensive way when referring to a group made up only of females or males.  The last option, "their", is still shunned by some purists, but is gaining sway as a gender-neutral singular possessive pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

The word would be "their" as in:

> "Everyone should make their part."