# Should a noun after the determiner *their* take in the form of singular or of plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, distributive-determiners

Should I say

> Some people use the word "flat" to describe their **phone** when **its battery** is dead.

or

> Some people use the word "flat" to describe their **phones** when **their batteries are** dead. (I wanted to use "their" here to refer to the phone's instead of the people's)

or

> Some people use the word "flat" to describe their **phones** when **their battery is** dead. (I wanted to use "their" here to refer to the phone's instead of the people's)

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Comment: The first two are equally fine, and there is no difference between them in normal language usage. The third one doesn’t work so well—when ‘phones’ is plural, ‘batteries’ is expected to be plural as well, otherwise it sounds like it’s the _person’s_ battery (car battery, for example) that’s dead, rather than the battery in their phone.

Comment: see http://www.englishforums.com/English/NounAfterTheir/brjhbr/post.htm

Comment: *Their* can be both plural and used as a non-gender specific replacement for singular *his/hers*.

Comment: I don't see any problem with any of these. Pronouns are normally slurred over, and there is no reason to fuss about whether the batteries belong to the phone or to the phone owner. When it's ambiguous, there's no pragmatic reason to distinguish, and when it's unambiguous, it still implies the other, so no sweat, let's get on to the next sentence, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that you want to refer to 'some people' for which the pronoun is obviously *their*) and 'their phones', but use a singular *battery*.  Put like that, it is clear that you will have to rephrase, since there is no correct pronoun for both singular *battery* and plural *phones*.
Your first example is common, but you should be aware that 'singular they', though commonly used, is also commonly criticised. (e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/8019) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/109840/8019)).

Your second is grammatical, but if there is a difference between 'the batteries belonging to the phones' and 'the batteries belonging to the people' (do you really think so?), then it is ambiguous, and cannot be rescued without changing the sentence: *when the battery is dead* or *...to describe phones with dead batteries* would be common rephrasings.

Your third is simply bad English (mixing singular and plural), unless, unusually, all the phones (or, of course, all the people) share one battery.

Answer (score 0):

The second example sentence should read "...describe their phones when **the** batteries are dead" and in the third, obviously, "...describe their phone (no 's') when **the** battery is dead. Otherwise it sounds as if you're saying the owner of the phone/s has a dead battery himself - 'their' is used to indicate possessive (the owner of the phone) 'the' refers to the battery within the phone, no possessive required.

Comment: But what I'm asking here is a grammar question on whether a noun after the determiner *their* should take in the form of singular or of plural. I'm not looking for a workaround to avoid ambiguity in the sentence such as introducing the determiner *the* and replacing it with *their* to better indicate that it is the batteries of the phones I'm trying refer to in the expressions.

Comment: I don't know which 'their' you're referring to, their phone or their batteries (meaning the phones). All I can reiterate as a native English speaker is you would never use two theirs in one sentence in this manner. not necessary and very confusing. And it can be either plural or singular after their (their gloves, their dogs, their phone, their scarf).

Comment: It's funny how your answer is not answering my question and you are trying to bring in the argument that you are a native English speaker and my sentence is too ambiguous that you couldn't figure out which "their" I'm referring to when I'd made it explicit by stating it in the brackets and informed you that this is a pure grammar question concerning the fact that if a noun after the determiner *their* should take in the form of singular or of plural.

Comment: Isn't bamboo allowed to address other issues he feels are relevant, on a site devoted to English Language and Usage? I wouldn't quibble about the ambiguity he correctly points out - it makes little difference to understanding here. I could probably find a case where it did lead to confusion if I could be bothered, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not quibbling. I'm simply informing him that I'm more concern about the grammar in this case and thus I didn't upvote this answer of his.

Comment: Hers, actually, thanks. Were I younger, I'd think I wasn't understanding the question - now I'm this vast age, still with fully functioning brain cells, I'm aware that if I don't understand what's being asked, it's cos its not clear. And I believe I said it could be singular or plural already....

Comment: I'm largely with Ms Bamboo on this one. The final sentence of your question is "Which one is grammatically correct? And why?". I accept that your main title specifically questions "the determiner after 'their'" - BUT when reading the main part of a question, it is easy to overlook the initial title, and to refer only to the question(s) within the main body. I've done it myself many times, and often I've edited questions to bring the title within the body. So PLEASE make sure that "main concern" is reflected in the question body itself.

Comment: @bamboo You are old doesn't mean you understand. Still wanna say thank you for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical instance of poor sentence construction in that the singular is used to artificially emphasise a point which then leaves a requirement for a common-gender personal pronoun singular which we don't have in English.
Example - "Every child should drink their milk"
Or worse - "A suicide bomber blew themselves up....."

Comment: You're a bundle of joy this morning (GMT).

Comment: Would you prefer "Some people use the word 'flat' to describe *his* phone"? Even if you don't believe the singular "they" is acceptable, that *"his"* is totally wrong, and option 2 is perfectly grammatical (and is also the version that sounds best to me).