# Ambiguity with appearance as plural or singular

Tags: grammar

It is more common to write: "People care too much about their appearance."
This is because it is being used as a "non count" noun and the plural could confuse people into thinking the writer means the occasion when someone is in a play, movie, etc. 
So with our would you still use singular?

Note that these dictionaries note it as being singular or plural (appearance as looks): http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/appearance
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appearance

Anyone shed light?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question? Please delete the previous question, [Complement ambiguity: Is the plural option incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302288/complement-ambiguity-is-the-plural-option-incorrect) as this question can't be deleted as it has an answer below. Please do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: Another question, [Appearances: Ambiguity in meaning](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302133/appearances-ambiguity-in-meaning). Just a heads-up. You could be suspended if you keep doing this. If it was a mistake to create two user names, please merge it visiting [Help Center  > My Account](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Please see my answer on the older question, and say whether it has been helpful http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302133/appearances-ambiguity-in-meaning

Answer (score 0):

The noun people has both a PLURAL sense and a SINGULAR sense. In the PLURAL sense, people is used as the plural of person very frequently. It is a plural count noun and takes a plural verb. It never has an -s ending; it is already plural.

I am not 100% sure about your question - where would you use "our"? Do you mean People care too much about our appearance? This doesn't make sense to me and I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question is about using **our** in place of **their**. If you didn't understand the question, please refrain from posting an answer. In addition, you can post a comment if you have more than 50 reputation points. The second paragraph of your post is not an answer, but a comment.