# "....their returns to campus" or "...their return to campus"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

> People resent their returns to campus.
>
> People resent their return to campus.

Should it be "returns," since each person is returning, and so there are multiple peoples returning? Or "return," since we are referring to people at large?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131430/should-a-noun-after-the-determiner-their-take-in-the-form-of-singular-or-of-pl

Comment: The professor was studying tax policy and wanted some data.  In response to his request, people resent their returns to campus.

Comment: @HotLicks They lifted not a finger for the university's traditions as students; as alumni, however, those fingers are constantly wagging at the current faculty and students for the state of the place. Perhaps the top fundraisers in the administration look forward to their reunion weekends, but most people resent their returns to campus.

Answer (score 1):

As [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/return_2) says, this sense of **return** is non-count:

> [SINGULAR/UNCOUNTABLE] a situation in which you go back to a place or
>   come back from a place
>
> return from: Harry had met Olivia shortly after his return from India.
>
> return to: Back at the hotel, John was packing for his return to
>   London.
>
> on someone’s return (from/to something): On her return to England, she
>   published an account of her travels.

So it's

*John looked forward to his return to campus*

and

*The students looked forward to their return to campus*.