# Using "their" vs. "his"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Why do we use *their* instead of *his* in this sentence?

> another driver flashes their lights

Answer (score 3):

Using *their* in this context suggests that you don't actually know the gender of the driver. If you used *his*, it would suggest that the driver is male. If you *know* that the driver is male, then it would be OK to use *his*.

Comment: Cool! So, I can use this everywhere? I mean, when writing a report, I can always say eg "user", and refer to him/her as "their" ? eg user turn off their devices

Comment: @pasq: That's a slightly more complicated question, see here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus

Comment: For the most part, you’re right that it means the gender is unspecified. However, there are documented cases where the gender is completely deterministic, but the speaker wished to create some notional distance between the speaker and the person spoken of.