# Other way of saying "with his/her back facing me."

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there another common way of saying: *with his/her back facing me?*

For example:

> The person was standing in the middle of the clearing,
>   **[...back...]** me.

I don't want to use **his/her** because I don't want to reveal the sex of the person.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Facing away from me? I would not believe a back could face you

Comment: Back doesn't "face" -- *with the back to me* (*He was sitting with the back to me so he couldn't see* ; *Aurimas, sitting with the back to me, was unable to see the huge smile on my face.* ; *the guard walks 2 meters, then stands fixed with the back to me*)

Comment: Backs **do** face, at least colloquially, as a [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="back+facing+me") reveals. That's not to say that there are not better ways of saying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the person's back is showing towards you, their face is looking the other way.

> The person was standing in the middle of the clearing, **facing away from me.**

An object like a cube has six sides or *faces* and you can use *facing* to relate its orientation to a particular face. You do this with your example sentence, "...[their] back facing me". But because people actually have one (and only one) ***face***, the verb is unambiguous when it does not qualify another part of the body.

As an aside, "his/her" could be replaced with *their*. [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus).

Comment: *In the middle of the clearing, back to me*, though not perfect, is an entirely acceptable elision.