# Which is recommended/preferable between '(s)he' & 'he/she'?

Tags: orthography, style-manuals, gender-neutral

When talking about or referring to someone who could either be a male or a female, I usually write it as ***[(s)he](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/(s)he)*** but I have also seen usage like ***[he/she](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/he/she#English)***, which also seems correct to me.

I use *(s)he* mostly because I find it shorter (fewer keystrokes). Are both *(s)he* and *he/she* correct? Any references are welcome.

And could ***[s/he](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/s/he#English)*** also be used?

Comment: You should use *they*.

Comment: That's really a Style Guide kind of a question... any of them could be used, or you could write the whole thing in "gender-neutral plurals" (using *they* everywhere), or you could define 'Jane, a typical user' and then refer to "her" the entire time.

Comment: @MattЭллен Yeah I know, I saw questions on gender neutrality related to this, but this question is asking whether a particular usage is correct or not, and which one should be used.

Comment: @Hellion Well, since I saw the other usage I began to question the one I personally used. That is, is it correct or not?

Comment: I believe that in formal writing it should be **he or she**. If you're writing emails to friends and colleagues, it's your choice. I might write **s/he** which use even fewer keystrokes!

Comment: I've worked on submissions where only one of your alternatives was considered correct  – the other was returned for 'correction'. I can't remember which it was, and I'm sure that others have met with the alternative stance. 'They' (used as singular) (yes, really) is probably the generally (though by no means universally) preferred option nowadays, as Matt seems to suggest. Eventually, you have to come to the conclusion that anyone _demanding_ a particular alternative here is setting themself (oops, him/herself) up as English Czar. We haven't got one.

Comment: @MattЭллен But since BleedingFingers is asking a specific question, it is unclear as to whether *they* (huh?) are (?) open to an alternative.

Comment: @bib 'Specific questions' of the nature 'Should it be a dozen eggs or twelve eggs?', or worse 'Does 3 + 4 = 6 or 8', are not offering scope for sensible answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It was intended more to be a genial poke at MattЭллен's logic than a prescriptive for answers.

Comment: @bib I used your genial poke to sneak in a minirant about a problem I feel occurs far too commonly in questions: 'Is A or B the correct construction?' where the answer 'C is the preferred construction' is met with 'But that's not the question asked by OP.'

Comment: @BleedingFingers, it's a matter of stylistic preference; none of them is "more correct" than the others.  So use whichever one makes your fingers bleed the least.

Comment: Yes, grammar is not there to cause you pain and anxiety. Take care of your fingertips and they will take care of you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA re **s/he**: does that not parse to you as *s or he*?  To generate *she or he* I would say you need *(s)he* or *she/he* based on the common general uses of slashes and brackets.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/2085.

Comment: If you use (s)he, for consistency don't you have to use h(er/im)? And h(i/er)s? I recommend not using any of these

Comment: To me, the main problem with "s/he" is not knowing how to pronounce it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a big chunk of your text and print it out in a few different ways, read it, and see which you prefer. There isn't a correct answer here.

Do pay attention to the visual - if you're using the phrase often enough, then your page may look like a mess of /'s or ()'s from a distance.

Personally, I'm biased towards "they" or rewriting so that your pronouns refer to an example person with a defined gender. This doesn't leave anyone out, especially folks who find neither "he" nor "she" to be a good fit for their gender. (Plus it avoids the aforementioned symbol overload.)

Answer (score 2):

You have asked a dangerous question.  I would use *he or she.*  The use of the genderless *they* is so widely accepted nowadays that questions regarding its use or non-use will not validate in standardized testing and, therefore, agreement is no longer tested on the SAT using the genderless *they.*  *S/he* looks tawdry to my eye because it is, at best, a novel use of the slash.  In the final analysis, the best answer will depend on your audience.  If they are in their 60s or older, I'd avoid the use of anything other than "he or she."  If they are younger, *he or she* still allows you to avoid the issue.  And I cannot say that *they* is wrong, despite the fact that hearing it pains my aged ears.

Comment: In these days of gender fluidity, perhaps _he and/or she_ might be a more encompassing option. ;-)

Comment: If you specifically want to embrace non-binary genders, why not use a [gender neutral pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns) for a more encompassing option? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both (s)he and he/she are acceptable abbreviations for usage where space is at a premium and gender of a person is important.

s/he is not a common abbreviation, and will confuse more users than the other two.

However, if at all possible, you should ignore the issue.   Inhuman beings can safely be referred to as "it" (ie, the cow and its feed), and while you can refer to humans that way as well you may not wish to for style reasons, and instead use gender neutral titles instead of pronouns.  (baby and baby's parent)

Comment: If the author tries to avoid all pronouns, the author's prose turns turgid and unreadable and the author quickly loses the author's audience.