# History of usage of singular "they" (gender-neutral)

Tags: history, literature, gender-neutral

I have just read in Emma by Jane Austen a phrase which surprised me:

> I can think of but one thing - Who is in love with her? Who makes you *their* confidant?
>
> (Jane Austen: Emma, Chapter VIII, Obreey PocketBook)

Here the lattest *who* is clearly in singular (followed by *makes*), the gender of the person under question is unknown, so I understand it as a *gender neutral their*:

> Who makes you *his/her* confidant? Who has confided you the information about her lover?

I wouldn't expect such an old usage of *their* functioning as a *singular gender neutral* word. I've always considered this "grammar trick" as a much more modern invention.

Is it really a usage of the gender neutral *their*? Is it so old that Jane Austen could have used it? Or was it just some recent editor who didn't consider the good old Austen "correct enough" and "fixed" it?

Comment: Shakespeare used it, and before him Chaucer.

Comment: The canonical answer on the usage of "singular they" is related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus ; however, though it says *Singular they enjoys a long history of usage in English*, it doesn't provide any more detail than that, and simply defers to the Wikipedia article on the subject.

Comment: With that said, the very Wikipedia article referenced calls out Austen specifically in its section "Older usage by respected authors": *"They" was already being used with a singular antecedent in the Middle English of the 14th century.It is found in the writings of many respected authors, including Chaucer, Shakespeare, **Jane Austen**, Thackeray, and Shaw"*, so maybe we should mark this question as a dupe of the other?

Comment: @Dan: please make your comment an answer, it's acceptable. My question was related purely to the *history* of the usage of *their* so I don't think it's a dupe. Thanks for your references.

Comment: http://www.crossmyt.com/hc/linghebr/austheir.html

Comment: I flagged it as a dupe already, so I don't know if it's kosher to answer as well. Maybe you can change the title to "history of usage of 'singular they'" or something, so it's clearly different from the other question? Then the mods can just ignore my flag.

Comment: @George: thanks for your link, I haven't realized it before how many occurences of singular *they* are in Jane Auste.

Comment: @Dan: done :-) if you now will remove your dupe flag and post your answer?

Comment: I didn't realize one could *unflag* something.  I'd be happy to do so, I'm not sure how: when I click on the "flag" link, it seems I'm able to add *additional* flags, but not remove one I applied previously. Any pointers?

Comment: @Dan: sorry, I was wrong, undoing your flag is not possible; http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/241944. So please at least post your answer.

Comment: http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the answer to the more general question of [whether singular *they* is proper English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) notes, the construction enjoys a long history of usage in English.

In fact, the [Wikipedia article on singular *they*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) has a section on the history of its use, and specifically calls out Austen as one of the respected, pre-modern authors who used *they* with a singular antecedent:

---

***Older usage by respected authors***

> *They* was already being used with a singular antecedent in the Middle English of the 14th century.  It is found in the writings of many respected authors, including Chaucer, Shakespeare, **Jane Austen**, Thackeray, and Shaw:
>
> "I would have every body marry if *they* can do it properly."— Austen, Mansfield Park (1814), quoted in Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage.
>
> "Had the Doctor been contented to take my dining tables as any body in *their* senses would have done..."— Austen, Mansfield Park (1814)