# Issue with the subject-verb agreement in the nonrestrictive clause?

Tags: commas, relative-clauses, dependent-clause

> Reading was very important to John's parents, both of them firsts in their families to go to college.

Is the nonrestrictive/relative clause "both of them firsts in their families to go to college" correct and has correct punctuation?

Or should it be "both of them being the firsts in their families to go to college"?

Should it be "first" instead of "firsts"; what rule governs it?

Another example:
X and Y are the firsts in this town to do Z

edit: fixed; posted the other Q separately.

Comment: There're some semantic difficulties: 'both,' does that mean John has exactly two brothers? Also, how can they both be first in their families since there is only one family here, and there can be only one first?

Comment: If they're twins? Or if they went to different types of colleges? Or if John's brothers grew up in different families, which is possible given the plural families. So yeah, more context for the first sentence. Is this something you found or wrote yourself? And what does 'cite' mean?

Comment: It's not a restrictive relative clause; no verb. It's a noun phrase  in apposition to _John's parents_. A cumbersome one, granted; the speaker is trying to pack too much into one sentence, a common problem.

Comment: Ok, so fixed the semantic issues with the sentence. Is it correct grammar? (even if the speaker is trying to pack too much)

Comment: Apologies for being pedantic, but shouldn't it be "...each of them first in his family..."?

Comment: @MBurke Typically one has one parent who is the first in **his** family and another who is the first in **her** family. Biologically, at least. It makes no sense to use *his* on a woman.

Comment: @tchrist This is true, except the last part.  In English, we don't use the gender-neutral  pronoun 'it' to describe a person, and since each person is singular we also shouldn't use 'they'.  We assume 'he' as in the phrase, "to each his own".  Does it make sense?  Is it sexist?  Off the point?  People argue.  Some just assume 'she'.  Also sexist?  Time will tell.  Saying 'his or her' all the time is just adding 2 extra words to every sentence.

Comment: @MBurke [Um, no. Sorry, that isn’t how English works.  You might like it to work that way for whatever reason, but it doesn’t.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55)

Comment: Simply because it is commonly done, doesn't mean it is correct.  However, I will consider myself corrected given the evidence here, and will begin to use what does in fact feel natural and use 'the singular they'.  I have simply been corrected too many times by various English teachers throughout my education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word category of ordinal numbers such as *first* is somewhat contentious. However, they behaves pretty much exactly like adjectives - which is what they probably are.

Consider the Original Poster's example:

- Reading was very important to John's parents, both of them firsts in their families to go to college.

Here we see *first* occurring without a following noun. This is similar to what we observe with other adjectives functioning as 'the head of noun phrases', such as *the rich* or *the poor*, *the disadvantaged* or *the good, the bad* and *the ugly*.

Adjectives in English do not inflect for number, unlike nouns. In fact this is one of the very reasons why some writers argue that ordinal numbers are adjectives and not nouns: they do not inflect for grammatical number and have no 'plural' forms:

- the elegant description
- *the elegants descriptions
- the first person
- *the firsts people

Even though there is no noun following *first* in the OP's example, *first* is still an adjective here. It therefore cannot have an 's' suffix to indicate plurality.

The example should therefore read:

- both of them **first** in their families to go to college.

Comment: upvoted for analysis.