# Is the use of "Them" right here?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

On StackOverFlow, the users who do not put anything in the profile have this displayed.

"Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.".

Should it not be him/her?

Clarifying before hand that English is not my strong point.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). You can find [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus/55#55) about *singular they* helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's correct. English literature is full of examples of *them* used as a gender-neutral pronoun, even when referring to one person. It's also a great way to refer to someone when you don't *know* their gender, or when you don't want to favour one or the other, e.g.:

"When our next customer walks in, please greet them."

Comment: Or when you don't want your parents to know their gender! "I'm going camping with a friend. I'm meeting them at Windermere".