# Who do we keep an air of mystery about?

Tags: reflexives

This is a followup to my post on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256333).

The filler text:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

sounds odd to my ear. I understand that "them" is being used as a singular, third-person gender neutral pronoun, but I don't think that's the issue. The analogous gender-specific constructions:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about him.
>
> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about her.

seem to be archaic and awkward, more naturally replaced by:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about him*self.*
>
> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about her*self*.

While it's true that ["an air of X about them"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20air%20of%22%20%22about%20them%22%20-site:stackoverflow.com%20-site:stackexchange.com) is at least a moderately-common construction in English, the construction ["*keep* an air of X"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=%22keep+an+air+of%22+-site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Astackexchange.com&oq=%22keep+an+air+of%22+-site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Astackexchange.com) is less common, so I don't think that the example of "There was an air of secrecy about them" is informative in this case.

I think the construction here is "to keep an X about Y" is the one that is important, and in the example of:

> They keep their friends close to *themselves* and their enemies closer.
>
> They keep their friends close to them and their enemies closer.

I'd say that the former is more correct than the latter.

I have no references for this, however, and I'm not sure where I would look. Is this a question of style, or grammar? Is there any authoritative reference for this? Is there an informative Google ngram search that would lean one way or the other?

Comment: That version of the phrase would be "They keep their friends close and their enemies closer"... I don't believe one would use "them" in that case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun ("his" versus "her" versus "their")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Comment: Wait - hold up. I was too trigger happy - close vote already retracted. That's not the question here! It's the choice between reflexive and non-reflexive - *them* vs. *themselves*. (*Themself*?) +1

Comment: @Daniel I'm not saying anything about they as a gender neutral singular pronoun, I'm asking about the proper reflexive to use here.

Comment: No worries! I responded before I saw.

Comment: From that google search, a relevant discussion (see post #10, which quotes from COCA: "She also always kept an air of mystery about her.")http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/keep-an-open-mindedness.2860663/

Comment: @Daniel What? You can retract a close vote? I thought that was impossible. How do you do that?

Comment: It clearly should be *themself*. But it is widely believed that word does not  exist.

Comment: @Mitch Yep, but you cannot close-vote again afterward (kinda like comment-votes). After voting to close, click on the *close* link again, then select *Retract close vote*, A popup asks if you are sure, since you can't vote again if you proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, The usage of [about](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/about) is different here. [Oxford]

You think it's used in sense 1

> On the subject of; concerning:

When in fact it's used in sense 3

> (chiefly British) Used to express location in a particular place:
>
> *rugs were strewn about the hall*

They're trying to say users keep an air of mystery **around** them

It's not used in this sense in AmE, maybe that caused the confusion.

See the 'Which Word?' segment in [this Oxford entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/about)

---

About the reflexive pronoun:

You are quite right in stating that even in this sense, subject and object are the same and so the reflexive pronoun is applicable. It isn't used for two reasons:

- "Air of mystery about him" is an old idiomatic way of putting it
- Using the reflexive emphasises the object, and so it is sometimes not used when this emphasis isn't desired, especially if the subject and object are unambiguously the same.

Compare:

- "He always keeps his diary with himself" (= he doesn't give it to anyone else.)
- "He always keeps his diary with him" (= he carries it around all day)

In "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.", the emphasis is desired on mystery, and it is highly unlikely anyone would interpret it to mean the user keeps the air about someone else.

Comment: Interesting. But isn't "an air of X" a metaphor over physical space? As in "there was an air of decay about the morgue." Or maybe "air" here is from a different origin? I know French has "avoir l'air de" -> [to appear a certain way](http://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_l%E2%80%99air). Maybe the English expression is a loan translation from that?

Comment: @PatrickCollins: The air of mystery isn't "over" the user. It's spread in all directions around them.

Comment: @Patrick: see [sense 4 here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/air). I don't see any implication of "over"

Comment: Actually I take back my first comment, I misread what you said. I agree that "about" here is in the sense of physical space, but I think that means it needs a reflexive pronoun: "she keeps an air of mystery around herself." Compare: "she keeps herself shrouded in mystery" vs "she keeps her shrouded in mystery." Keeps who? The reflexive pronoun is necessary.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Valid point, but I think you're misreading the intent. Both `about` and `her` were used in old formal constructions. "The wizard had an air of arrogance about him" has less ambiguity than the way you phrased it (with `keep`). This construction was pretty common before and is still found in fantasy works.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22air+of%22+%22about+him%22)

Comment: I agree, but it's archaic and awkward -- unless the SO team intends to sound old and formal, it should read "themselves." I suppose it's only an issue of style, though.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Oh! But it does. Archaic forms are very often used for humour. Websites are coming up with innovative ways to not bore their visitors. IMDb never says 404 not found. It quotes a line from a movie. This is SE's way. And it works, imo.

Comment: And although "an air of mystery about him" is somewhat common, I don't think it applies here, since "keep" makes the whole thing a transitive, and so, since the subject and object are the same thing, the object should be reflexive.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: Again, you're right, but there _are_ other cases where the subject and object are same but the reflexive is conventionally not used because they are (almost) _unambiguously_ the same. "He always keeps his diary with him(self)". Dropping the reflexive has the additional effect of emphasising the subject/verb rather than the object. "He always keeps his diary with himself" = he doesn't give it to anyone else. "He always keeps his diary with him" = he carries it around all day.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: the problem with using "themselves" is that for some people, like me, the more natural variant here would be "themself", which is not recognized as an established word by many people.