# Is it right to replace "it depends on the person and his/her environment" to it depends on the person and their environment"?

Tags: grammar

Please provide an alternate statement too(if any).

Comment: Yes, it is OK. So-called ["singular _they_"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf) is standard, normal, colloquial English -- spoken and written. It has been for centuries, and anybody who tells you different is simply demonstrating their ignorance of English grammar.

Comment: You can say *his or her*, you can use *his/her*, you can default to *her*, you can use *his* and *her* in alternating examples, you can say *the person's*, and so on and so on, but *their* is surely the simplest if you must avoid *his*. See *[Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun ("his" versus "her" versus "their")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)*