# Send an invitation and let the user create their own password

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they, agreement

> Send an invitation and let the user create their own password

In this sentence *user* is singular, and *their* is plural. So I am confused whether this sentence is correct or not.

Is this sentence correct? If not how can I correct it?

Comment: This is a case of singular "their". A good post about this is http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus . Another good place to look is Language Log http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=89 the link I'm providing isn't perfect but searching around on LL will find you many more examples. In summary singular they/their used as a gender neutral pronoun is perfectly acceptable according to most linguists. There are some grammarians that might still object though.

Comment: Your premise that *their* must be “plural” is completely incorrect, and whatever book you read that in should be consigned to the pyre. It is utterly common to use *their* with a singular referent, just as it is utterly common to use *your* with a singular referent — as you **yourself** I’m sure will clearly see.

Comment: _You_ is also "plural" (and takes plural verb agreement), but somehow we forgot to notice that about 300 years ago. Silly us.