# Usage of a pronoun properly

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

I had this question in mind for long and I think this is the perfect spot to ask.

Consider the following sentences (Just for instance).

> We are an equal opportunity employer. However when applying for this job he/she should also mention his/her gender.

So my question is, is there any other proper usage for he/she or his/her instead especially if the description is getting longer ?

Comment: How about 'However, applicants should also mention their gender.'

Comment: There are a number of related questions. How about [gender-neutral singular pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thankyou. Now its clear.

Comment: Note that 'generally' and 'acceptable to all' are generally not equivalents.