# Gender-neutral pronoun other than singular they?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

I'm looking for a singular, gender-neutral pronoun that can be used when the speaker doesn't know or want to disclose a person's gender. For example, take this sentence:

> **He** is coming with us.

I've looked for some alternatives on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/121639), but "they" gives the impression that multiple people are coming along:

> **They** are coming with us.

"One" doesn't fit in this context, and I'd prefer to avoid using he/she if possible.

Is there a commonly used alternative to singular they?

Comment: No, "They are coming with us" does not give the impression that more than one person is involved: “You need to call somebody to watch your back. They are coming with us.”

Comment: You could say: "Someone is coming with us". I agree that "They are coming with us" in **isolation** strongly suggests that the subject is plural. But it does work if context is provided e.g. *The agency said this area was too dangerous to walk alone at night, so someone is / they are coming with us.*