# If I'm not sure about the gender of Brown may I write "Brown was merry and their cat was sad"?

Tags: word-usage

If I'm not sure about the gender of Brown may I write:

> Brown was merry and their cat was sad.

... ? I met such a construction in "Harry Potter", but I don't know whether native speakers are happy with it.

In particular, is it ok to use *they* after we have actually used the name of a specific individual and it is clear that the case in point is a *single* person?

Comment: [It's fine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48).

Comment: Maybe you could actually give the construction ... the information you have given here isn't enough for me to decide whether I'd be happy with it.

Comment: I think the actual duplicate is a question put by they who used to add 'I acknowledge the etymological fallacy' owtte. It asks about whether 'they' is appropriate for a named antecedent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not, at least according the rules for singular *they* that I absorbed when I was growing up. The relevant rule is that you cannot use singular *they* for somebody you refer to by name. So you can say:

> Somebody named Leslie called, and they want you to call them back. (The referent is *someone*.)

But not

> Leslie called, and they want you to call them back. (The referent is *Leslie*.)

This grammatical rule seems to be changing, in that more people are finding these constructions acceptable nowadays, especially since some alternatively gendered people want to be referred to as *"them"* (something I would have a hard time doing). However, I would still recommend rewriting the sentence to avoid breaking this rule.

And one last comment: if you don't know Brown's sex, how do you know that he or she was merry (unless it's hard to tell Brown's gender by looking at him or her)?

Comment: Is the possessive *their* following the same usage trajectory as *they*?

Comment: Thank you, @Peter Shor . What about the intermediate case (a common noun)? "The owner was merry and ?? cat was sad."

Comment: *"The owner was merry and their cat was sad"* sounds perfectly fine to me, even if it's clear you should know the gender of the owner. However, I wouldn't be surprised if some people use the rule: don't use singular *they* when you know the person's gender.

Comment: @Phil: I believe the possessive *their* is following the same trajectory as *they*.