# Is this the correct way to write this sentence?

Tags: sentence, pronouns

Okay, so I came across a strange, yet interesting dilemma, There was an English test in my high school in which I got a challenging MCQ. Here it is:
**Anyone can have ________ name in the newspaper.**
Choices given were:
**1- Their

2- His

3- Her**
I selected the option 1, all my friends did! But my teacher sort of challenged me to verify whether I was correct or not! I'm not sure myself, so I'm asking this question on Stack Exchange. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: No matter *how* old you are, it's not really a matter of "his / her" being objectively *correct*. Per the top answer to the original question of which this is a duplicate: [*Singular **they** enjoys a long history of usage in English*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/2637). Many pedants and grammarians have worked tirelessly over generations to teach/bully children into changing the way native speakers *actually* use the language. But as usual, they've had little effect. We speak the way our peers do, not the way teachers *tell* us to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I learned grammar, the correct answer would have been "**his**" or "**his or her**," as the antecedent "**anyone**" is clearly singular. However, these days people accept the plural "**their**" as a pseudo-singular possessive pronoun, so most people would accept your answer as correct. Still, it is good form to know about pronoun-antecedent agreement so that you can intelligently defend your answer.

**[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)** is a Wikipedia article on the topic, if you are interested in learning more. (Also click on the link recommended by FumbleFingers in his excellent comment, above.)