# third person - personal pronoun for AI ( Artificial Intelligence )?

Tags: personal-pronouns

I'm brainstorming on the architecture for an AI system - and describing the interaction with the world - i keep getting back on the question of - how do i refer him/she/it on the **third person**?

**Him** or **She** or **It** ?

**None of this pronouns capture what it is.**

Technically is not an **it** - since it has the potential to be conscious.

Let's take a hypothetical scenario: just makes me wonder

The design comes with a spec. A `spec` is more or less like a law; describes and enforces the state and behavior of a computational system.

If this **it** takes upon itself to check the dictionary definition of **it** - and seeing it  - decides that it can not possibly be an **it** - then maybe it can disregard the spec. The `spec` can dictate it's behavior only if **it**'s an **it**.  (this sounds more like a weak terminator movie plot then reality :)))

Invent a new new pronoun used just for AI? Maybe **ait** (only it doesn't conjugate very well). Just googling I could not find any good resources on this.

**I think it comes a time to address this issue in a formal way..**

What do we do? Is it ok to use **it** for Artificial Intelligence ?

What is a "by the book" approach to this types of questions?

What would be the specific answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on current trends, the pronoun "they" is acceptable to refer to a single person of unknown or no gender, as addressed in a [more broad question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/243336). Whether you should use "they" or "it" in this particular context is more of a philosophical debate than a linguistic one.