# Why does English use singular they instead of making up a new word for this?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, neologisms, singular-they, grammatical-gender

Why does English use [singular *they*](https://www.cambridge.org/elt/blog/2020/11/16/singular-they-teaching-a-changing-language/) instead of making up a new word for this?

In my native language there’s a word *dia* which has the same meaning as *he/she*, but it doesn’t give information about the gender of that person.

I’ve seen questions close to this, but they don’t provide the reason for **not** making up a new word for this distinct meaning.

Comment: People have proposed new words. See Arjan's answer to a very frequently viewed question on this site, [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun {“his” vs. “her” vs. “their”}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5348/77227)

Comment: *Why* questions about language are almost always poor candidates for good answers as they are often subject to personal opinion. Language is what people make of it, and, at least currently, the use of the singular *they* is seeing a resurgence.

Comment: Why does your language just have one word _dia_ which doesn’t specify whether you’re talking about a man or a woman? Why haven’t they made up a pronoun that specifies the gender?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure where Albert comes from. But when I lived in Japan decades ago, and made an effort at Japanese, I found the non-gender specific pronouns, and particularly the title San (which can mean Mr, Mrs, Miss or Ms) quite inconvenient. And since the Japanese are loathe to refer to people with given names, I found myself sometimes needing to ask, at the company where I worked, when a name was mentioned - "Is Nishi-san a man or a woman" which felt lame and awkward. No doubt I will be taken to task for this but I felt handicapped in having to think in a genderless way.

Comment: @WS2 Japanese does have gendered pronouns (masculine 彼 _kare_ vs feminine 彼女 _kanojo_), though they are of course less likely to use them than English. I’ve sometimes felt it was a hindrance in languages like Finnish or Chinese where there really are no gendered pronouns at all, but more often than not, it doesn’t really present a problem in my experience – context usually makes it either clear or unimportant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry, I've long forgotten most of the Japanese I learned. Re "clear or unimportant" - that's what the Japanese told me. Perhaps that is the case when you are brought up that way. It would be an interesting sociological study, to see if those languages that were less gender specific, produced people who were less gender aware. It certainly didn't seem like that to me, in Japan at that time - where gender specific roles seemed even more marked than in Britain.

Comment: Lexicon Valley had a podcast about this topic recently: https://www.booksmartstudios.org/p/on-the-singular-they-and-slippery (and an earlier episode in 2018: https://slate.com/human-interest/2018/08/singular-they-pronoun-john-mcwhorter-says-it-s-time-to-embrace-it.html)

Comment: In accordance with my [old meta discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11910/191178) (which received almost unanimous support for this question being open), I'm going to get this reopened. If you disagree, argue your case on meta.

Answer (score 43):

People *have* created new gender-neutral pronouns. They are known as **neopronouns**. (A good list of currently used ones can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Summary).) Furthermore, the move to create gender-neutral pronouns in English is quite old. However, none of these pronouns were ever very successful. Few people are even aware they exist. Currently, these new pronouns are usually confined to the transgender/non-binary/queer community, but even there singular *they* is preferred by the majority (for those who don't use *he* or *she*), as found by [The Trevor Project](https://www.thetrevorproject.org/2020/07/29/research-brief-pronouns-usage-among-lgbtq-youth/), [Nonbinary Wiki's surveys](https://nonbinary.wiki/w/index.php?title=Pronouns&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile#Surveys), and (as they do yearly) [Gender Census](https://gendercensus.com/results/).

People often say they don't like the way these new pronouns sound ([example from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/249cma/cmv_i_think_that_gender_neutral_pronouns_such_as/)). Pronouns are used very frequently, and it's definitely jarring to not hear what you're expecting. It's even worse when speaking, having to think and make a conscious decision to switch *every single time* you use a pronoun. This is mentioned in the book [What is Morphology?](https://books.google.com/books?id=bolGMMyZVjMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22One+generalization+we+can+make+is+that+while+content+%22.):

> One generalization we can make is that while content words are
> an open class and it is possible to coin new ones, function words are
> a closed class. A person cannot easily invent a new preposition or
> conjunction. Perhaps most telling is the long history of people trying
> to invent a gender-neutral singular pronoun for English. Suggestions
> have included *co, et, hesh, na, e,* and *thon*. Some linguists have recently proposed *tey* (on the analogy of plural *they*, which is gender-neutral), with further forms *tem* and *ter* (modeled on *them* and *her*). None of these novel words has caught on, while novel content words like
> *modem* and *cell phone* enter the language relatively smoothly.

[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2015/jan/30/is-it-time-we-agreed-on-a-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun) has a very good summary of the history:

> [Baron's blog](https://blogs.illinois.edu/view/25/31097) walks you through all the failed attempts – starting with the mid 19th century's *ne*, *nis*, *nim*, and citing sci-fi's contributions of neologism: *co*; *xie*; *per*; *en*. As early as 1878, Napoleon Bonaparte Brown argued that the need for a new pronoun was "so desperate, urgent, imperative that ... it should long since have grown on our speech".
>
> In 1884, *thon*, *hi*, *le*, *hiser* and *ip* were variously suggested. *Thon* – a blend of *that* and *one* – was coined by Philadelphia lawyer Charles C Converse and Baron demonstrates how it was the closest thing to a successful attempt at entering the vernacular; it was accepted by two major dictionaries and even adopted by some writers. But it was grammatical pedantry, not feminism, that motivated Converse. He wanted a "beautiful symmetry" in English and to avoid "hideous solecisms".
>
> The second closest thing to enter the vernacular was named after American mathematician Michael Spivak; initially *e*, *es*, *em* (e wrote; es eyes are blue) later *ey*, *eir*, *em* (ey wrote; I like em). [Other sources](https://genderneutralpronoun.wordpress.com/tag/ze-and-zir/) attribute these pronouns (formed by dropping the th from they, their and them) to a competition run by the Chicago Association of Business Communicators, won by a Christine M Elverson in 1975. The Spivak pronouns are used today by some in the genderqueer and gaming communities.
>
> Further proposals – *hes*, *hem*, *ir*, *ons*, *e*, *ith*, *lim*, *ler*, *lers* – sprang up, often suggested by newspapers. Readers suggested portmanteaus: *hiser*; *himer*; *hasher*; *shis*; *shim*; *heer*; *hie*. Humanist lexicon suggested *hu*, which can occasionally sound like the Kiwi accent (*hu* wrote; I like *hum*). [Jayce's system](https://jayceland.com/blog/archive/2011/01/30/jayces-gender-neutral-pronouns), meanwhile, suggested *jee*, *jem* (jee wrote; I like jem). You can find these, and many more, listed at *[A Chronology of a Word that Failed](https://web.archive.org/web/20101018064736if_/http://www.english.illinois.edu/-people-/faculty/debaron/essays/epicene.htm)*.
>
> Why has a need for such a short and simple word been so unsuccessful? One opponent of the "bastard word form" portmanteaus, wrote in the New York Commercial Advertiser in 1884 in response to the idea of thon: "All attempts in this direction have failed, partly because it is always exceedingly difficult to introduce new forms into a language, unless they spring up naturally and, as it were, spontaneously."

### Other alternatives

#### None

One technique is to use no pronouns at all. This means that you use a mix of the person's name and perhaps also other context-dependent nouns such as "your friend". The downside is that it can feel clumsy and repetitive if you have to keep saying the person's name, plus it is a cognitive effort to do so instead of a pronoun if you are not accustomed to it. It's not uncommon to see this as a "pronoun" choice in the transgender/non-binary/queer community (as some polls say), and even by a few people online outside that. It's also an extremely common technique to employ when telling a story to someone, when a third party's name is mentioned but not gender.

#### It's the other third person gender-neutral singular

"It" crops up in many discussions of this type, especially by nonnative speakers. But just as quickly, it is dismissed, because the pronoun it almost always refers to objects, not people. And, in general, when it does refer to people, ["It" Is Dehumanizing](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItIsDehumanizing). There are only a few exceptions, the most common one being babies, and the more obscure case being a small percent non-binary individuals (but not that small — [Gender Census 2021](https://gendercensus.com/results/2021-worldwide/#pronouns) recorded that 9.3% would be "happy for people to use" the pronoun *it* for them). Still, association with objects makes *it* unsuitable for use in general: don't use *it*.

---

### Historical context: Your polite pronoun

As it turns out, English went through an extremely similar transition before, with the other plural to single pronoun: *you*.

The Oxford English Dictionary summarizes the change (you can also read their [entry for "you"](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/232147) for free):

> The use of *you* as a ‘polite' form of address to a single person progressively encroached on *thou* (originally the singular pronoun) until by 1600 *thou* (and its objective case *thee*) was restricted to ‘affective' (both positive and negative) uses (i.e. so as to be intimate or disparaging). By the late seventeenth century *you*  had become normal in almost all contexts and *thou* and *thee* were limited to the Bible and religious use, the Quakers, and regional dialects.

Indeed, the Quakers of old especially rejected singular *you*:

- George Fox, the founder of Quakerism, wrote [an entire battledoor](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A40123.0001.001/1:2?rgn=div1;view=fulltext) (i.e. a textbook) on the subject (1660).
- William Penn, who founded Pennsylvania, dedicated a [chapter of his book](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=evans;cc=evans;rgn=main;view=text;idno=N04838.0001.001) to the subject (1669).
- > It was first ascribed in way of *Flattery* to Proud Popes and Emperors; imitating the Heathens vain Homage to their Gods; thereby ascribing a *Plural* Honour to a *single* Person; as if *One* Pope had been made up of *many* Gods, and *One* Emperor of *many* Men. For which Reason, *You,* only to be used to *many,* became first spoken to *One.*

  - (↑ In the first person, this describes Royal *we*.)

### Frequency of use

I decided to do some corpora research to see how popular different pronouns are. To make it easier, I decided to just look at the *-self* form, which allows me to use a single search. I used [an iWeb search for `*self`](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/?c=iweb&q=80469360), and then searched the results. Here's what I found:

- Themselves: ??? (Potentially the most popular, but there's no easy way to sort out plural from singular)
- Themself: 5369 hits

  - I did not sort through this, so this number may include some plural usage and duplicates
  - An additional 15-20 or so hits come from typos and similar nonstandard versions such as theirself, thereself, and themeself.
- Hirself: 40 hits (excludes quotes of older sources which meant "herself")

  - 23 different websites
- Emself: 43 hits

  - 6 different websites (most hits are from a single site)
- Xirself: 35 hits

  - 1 website
- Xemself: 6 hits

  - 4 sites
- Zirself: 5 hits

  - 3 sites
- Perself: 3 hits
- Xumself: 1 hit
- Xyrself: 1 hit
- Ximself: 1 hit
- Zeself: 1 hit
- Zieself: 1 hit

Also note:

- There were several different variations of himself/herself, but I didn't make a list of them
- Humself: This showed up, but all the hits were typos for "himself"
- Zemself: The one result is a rant about gender pronouns
- I went through the *entire* list by hand, but I didn't look at the context for everything, so I may have missed some words.

Comment: People have *tried* to create gender-neutral pronouns, but all attempts have failed so far, as the Guardian journalist noted.

Comment: Short version - just because a word is cromulent doesn't mean people will use it.

Comment: A further complication with *thon* is that some dialects have demonstrative pronoun *thon* as a variant of *yon*. While there are of course plenty of homonyms in English, it would be a source of further resistance where *thon* is already in use in a very different meaning.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to curate your answer.

Comment: This is absolutely fascinating!

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  and yet one year later you cast your vote to close the question that attracted this fascinating answer. No great answers would have been posted  if the newly (and inexplicable) off-topic question had been closed in 2018. Are the answers now meaningless? No. Could someone in the future else shed further light, not now. P.S I already used up my reopen vote. Due to an unfathomable logic, this question has been closed a 2nd time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: My apologies! While reviewing the question in the Review Queues, I only read the question cast my CV due to obvious reasons (opinion-based + lack of research). However, I'll vote to re-open it (only for the excellent answers).

Answer (score 19):

Mostly, because they already have singular *they*. It's been in the language since the 14th century. Prior to that, there was generic *he*, which continued to also be used until the 20th century and is still found. There are also the inclusive doubles "he/she" and "s/he" ("inclusive" though not as inclusive as we might want, on which more below).

The earliest reasons for wanting an alternative to both singular *they* and generic *he* that was an explicitly third-person, singular, gender-neutral pronoun came not so much out of sexual politics (whether to ignore gender where it isn't known or relevant, or to describe non-binary people) but the 18th century dislike of words that did not neatly fit; *They* being grammatically plural and *he* also having a specifically masculine use that wasn't clearly distinguished from its generic use upset the same sort of people that got upset by *less* being used of both countable and uncountable terms while *fewer* could only be used of countable.

This encouraged people to desire such a pronoun, but it wasn't a pressing need.

Later, the undesirable ability of generic *he* to carry an assumption of masculinity with it made it increasingly unwelcome, especially when the political implications gained more attention, such that it is now largely obsolete, but *they* and "he/she" still served enough that most people didn't feel any need to adopt *ze*,  *thon*,* or other suggested pronouns.

In particular, if someone wanted to specifically indicate singularity and also wanted to be neutral as to gender, but were not considering genders other than male and female (which tended not to be considered until relatively recently) then "he/she" filled that gap. Meanwhile *they* continued in informal use in almost all forms of English, as much as it was considered improper by some.

Conversely, while people are beginning to be more respectful of other genders, the argument against grammatical plurality being used with singular antecedents has lost favour. As such a reason why people may have favoured *he* over *they* 150 years ago or "he/she" over *they* 50 years ago is no longer as strongly with us.

That *they* is the pronoun preferred by a great many non-binary and gender-queer people today continues to reduce the pressure to do otherwise. While those who do favour an explicitly singular gender-neutral pronoun will lead us to use *ze* of zir, or *thon* of thon, it doesn't lead to a strong pressure to replace *they* and *them* in other uses.

In all, while we've had different reasons to be unhappy with the position of *they*, *he* and "he/she" over the centuries, we haven't had any reason to be happy with any particular alternative.

---

*Note also that *thon* is a variant of *yon* in some dialects, or of meaning something yet further away than something *yon*, which wouldn't have been a big pressure against adoption, but would still have been a slight pressure. There are of course plenty of homonyms in the language, but being a homonym does add resistance to adoption of new terms.

Answer (score 12):

Because creating a new *closed-class* word is a **hugely** invasive change to people's way of speaking.

It's much more drastic than creating a new noun (euphemism) for an old (derogatory) noun. The difference is that you can to a certain degree choose which noun you use to describe people or concepts, but you can't opt out of using a pronoun because there is only one for one feature combination.

Also, to get a new pronoun adopted, the speech community would have to adjust processes that are much more automatic and ingrained than to adopt a new euphemism. This makes people liable to view it as unjustified interference in their personal affairs and hate every new proposal on principle (often rationalizing their opposition on grounds such as "it sounds ugly").

Ultimately, people are likely to get on board with such a change  only if they view the underlying agenda for social change as justified - and sexual politics is a divisive issue on which large segments of the population have quite irreconcilable views. In general, using language as an instrument of social change has a bad historical record as opposed to bringing about the change and then watching language adapt.

Answer (score 10):

There's no authority for English, even for a single major English-speaking country, so there's no-one to mandate the existence of a new word, never mind its use.  Such authorities tend to move slowly, and prefer established words to creating new ones in the same niche, and there are arguments for *he* as well as *they* as a gender-neutral singular (linguistic arguments that miss the point). So we consider the situation where ordinary people want to use gender-neautral language.

If someone tried to coin a new word to replace singular *they*, they'd have trouble even getting people to recognise that the  mystery new word is a pronoun. Then this new word gets flagged up by a spell checker if someone tries to reuse it, so hardly anyone bothers; they rephrase the sentence instead.  Fundamentally though, it's just not necessary, people have been using singular *they* for years, they¹ just don't realise it – did you on reading this paragraph?

Or to rewrite that with one of the more common alternative suggestions:

> If someone tried to coin a new word to replace singular *they*, ze'd have trouble even getting people to recognise that the  mystery new word is a pronoun. Then this new word gets flagged up by a spell checker if someone tries to reuse it, so hardly anyone bothers; ze rephrases the sentence instead.

Some constructions, like *(s)he*, are clear enough, but are only gender neutral on the assumption of two traditional genders, and there's a feeling that if we're going to make an effort to be neutral, we should do it properly.

When used in writing, it's often not clear how such a word would be pronounced, when spoken, (assumptions of mishearing aside) it's not clear how they'd be spelt.

---

¹ OK, that one's plural.

Comment: My example was actually accidental at first; it's the natural product of trying to write clearly and neutrally (wihtout claiming to succeed at either)

Answer (score 7):

A lan­guage is not made by “think­ing of a trans­la­tion” for a word. For
ex­am­ple, it’s not like you have the Ja­panese word *kon­nichi­wak* and
then ask your­self “How do we say this in English?”, and fol­low­ing that
then an­swer your­self “Oh let’s use the word *hi*”.

That’s not how it works – be­cause there **is** no English word for
*kon­nichiwa*. It be­longs only to the Ja­panese lan­guage and to the
Ja­panese lan­guage alone. If you want to trans­late text into English,
you’re **not sup­posed to trans­late** it word by word.  The goal of
trans­la­tion is in­stead to con­vey the **mean­ing** of the orig­i­nal
rather than to trans­late its text word by word in a me­chan­i­cal
fash­ion.

For in­stance, English has **a lot** of ad­jec­tives. Not all of these have
their own trans­la­tion in other lan­guages.  Again the goal of
trans­la­tion is to con­vey the orig­i­nal mean­ing. It so hap­pens that
when I say *kon­nichiwa* in Ja­panese and when I say *hi* in English, they
both con­vey a greet­ing.

Another ex­am­ple: when some­one asks if you want to go out for cof­fee,
you could an­swer *I’d love to.* But if you trans­late that to a
dif­fer­ent lan­guage, in Filipino you could say  *oo*. Three sen­tences
trans­lated into one word? If you trans­late it word by word in­nto
English, you’d get *oo ini­ibig ko* – which is hon­estly not very nor­mal
in Filipino. So you could just use *oo*, which is just as sim­ple as *yes*
is. The pur­pose was to con­vey the mes­sage that you wanted tea, no more
and no less.

> Un­less it’s pointed out that you have to em­pha­size that you’d
>   ***love*** some tea, then you could say *ay oo gus­tong gusto ko* –
>   which ac­tu­ally also trans­lates dif­fer­ently; word by word, it
>   would be “Oh yes, I do want tea.”

So it’s not that they don’t **want** to cre­ate a new word for it: it’s
just that its mean­ing **is con­veyed dif­fer­ently in English** than it is
in the orig­i­nal.  They *could* cre­ate a new word for it, but be­cause it can
al­ready be prop­erly con­veyed with­out one, they feel no press­ing need.

So in my opin­ion I don’t think there is any need to cre­ate a new word for
this.

Comment: The necessity for a pure gender-neutral pronoun is most sought after by the LGBTQ community, there is a "need" and some have proposed several solutions but they haven't really caught on with the general public. Using "he or she" or "they" for an individual who is non-binary can be interpreted as being offensive, or more generously, lacking in sensitivity.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers note, the history of trying to invent a gender-neutral singular pronoun in English is littered with failures, nonce usages, and usages that become popular in insular communities but don't catch hold in dialect-wide populations. Indeed, while any invented word has hurdles to overcome before it is accepted and widely used, *pronouns* are an especially difficult class of word to change. Why is that? What would have to happen for an invented gender neutral pronoun to be accepted in English?

### How does a pronoun become established in English?

In short: a linguistic need arises and a nearby available tool is adopted to meet it.

First, pronouns have not been invented often in the history of English. The most widely-known example is the importation of *they/them/their* from Old Norse instead of *hie/hem/hier*, which is widely documented in texts on Old and Middle English (see e.g. [Brown 2009](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mp7j_xqKQ9IC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=old%20english%20hie%20hem&source=bl&ots=sQ5kjGzAu-&sig=ACfU3U01NbbxcOj_smjKIhI0peb9phUXIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig5MbWya3lAhVlS98KHc0PCVgQ6AEwDXoECAcQAQ)). In this case, the change started with Norse settlement in the north of England, and grew over a few centuries. It helped that the forms weren't that far off from the Old English pronouns, and that *they/them/their* provided the additional benefit of being clearly distinguished from other pronouns like *he*, *him*, and *her*. So a possible need for disambiguating pronouns was met by a nearby tool - an adjacent language's pronouns.

Newer pronominal forms like *yinz* and *y'all* have formed within dialects from the 19th century onward ([Crystal 2011](https://books.google.com/books?id=4djICT7zgGoC&lpg=PA173&dq=%22y'all%22%20%22usage%22&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The history of *y'all* shows how a need (how to distinguish a plural second person after the separate singular form *thou* disappears from use) is met with adding a modifier (*you all*), how that modifier was gradually contracted (*y'all*), and even how that existing form has now sometimes been adopted as a *singular* pronoun (as Crystal reports: "Howdy y'all" and "Y'all take care now" being delivered to one person).

In contrast, neologistic pronouns usually don't stick around. Pronouns are considered a *closed class* ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-closed-class-words-1689856)), which means that new words usually don't catch on to the class. That's why I don't have any examples of wildly successful pronouns made *ex nihilo*.

To adapt this pattern to the current situation:

- We need a gender-neutral third person pronoun
- The resulting pronoun will most likely be an existing tool adapted to the new situation, since they're joining a *closed class* of word

### What Are the Likely Candidates for Inclusion?

**They/Them/Their/Themselves/Themself**
As you note, one word is already being widely adopted for use as a gender-neutral singular pronoun: singular *they*. Present in English since the 14th century, especially for following singular antecedents like *anyone* and *someone*, singular *they* has also been adopted as a pronominal set by people who desire a gender-ambivalent option. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/singular-nonbinary-they) describes its growth:

> They is taking on a new use, however: as a pronoun of choice for someone who doesn’t identify as either male or female. This is a different use than the traditional singular they, which is used to refer to a person whose gender isn’t known or isn’t important in the context [...] The new use of they is direct, and it is for a person whose gender is known, but who does not identify as male or female. If I were introducing a friend who preferred to use the pronoun they, I would say, “This is my friend, Jay. I met them at work.”

So we have a need for people who don't identify as male or female to have a pronoun suited to them, and a tool that - while not originally nonbinary - did escape the conventional association with a single gender. So people who heard it and didn't initially understand its use would have a better chance of puzzling it out, or remembering its use afterwards. That makes *they* an effective option.

Variants like **themself** also show considerable promise, since the form *predates *themselves** but had fallen in popularity in the early modern period ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/themself)). It encounters the problem that *themselves*, with the plural *selves*, may be perceived as plural in singular contexts. Having the available historical context, and the well-known word *self* available, helps the argument for *themself*, though it has not caught on widely in publications.

**Other Pronouns - What Might Stop Them?**
Other proposed pronouns include *xe* and *xir*, *hir*, and many others ([UWM](https://uwm.edu/lgbtrc/support/gender-pronouns/)). They involve changing vowels or consonants to create new and distinct forms. These forms have big hurdles that they need to overcome:

- familiarity, or how to make these sound comprehensible and clear upon a first or second usage, compared to the other available options
- pronunciation, or how to make the sounds

*Xe* and *hir* do okay, at least in writing, because they are relatively close to a recognizable pronoun. With *xe*, a reader can puzzle out that the *h*/*sh* of *he* or *she* have been replaced by an *x* that is neither one. *Hir* looks kind of halfway between *him* and *her*. Neither is quite as familiar as *they*.

Regarding pronunciation, it may not be clear how to pronounce the *x* in *xe*: is it /zi/ or /ɛksˈi/ or /ʃi/? With *hir*, it may not be clear how to distinguish the vowel from related vowels, like the one in *her*. Neither are insurmountable with a little teaching, but that in itself poses an issue in a closed system - new pronouns have tended to spread without being formally taught. So it will take some time to see if the proponents of these new pronouns can make the words catch on.

So combined, issues of familiarity and pronunciation may hinder these other pronouns from taking their place in the general population, even if they're familiar to the LGBT community and many of their allies. Even if, in theory, we agree that a totally separate third person nonbinary pronoun would be better, *they* benefits from being more familiar and easier to say.

Comment: I very much appreciate  that you have provided a substantial answer complete with professional references such as Brown or Crystal. Your answer is very much appreciated. I really had hoped that the asker would return sometime this past week and award the Great Green Checkmark of Helpfulness either to your answer or to Laurel’s so that my conscience of equanimity could award the bounty to whichever of the two answers remained ungarlanded following said selection. Alas it was not to be. But such a good answer as yours very much merits community acclaim and upvotes, so I hope you stil get those.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in a language like Japanese, pronouns are a closed class. That means it's really hard to create a new personal pronoun (unlike Japanese where they fall in and out of favor over the span of decades). "They" has simply been around longer, so all the various neopronouns (e.g. xe, zir) never really caught on.

The only instances I'm aware of where a closed-class neopronoun has caught on are:

1. Various dialectal English second-person plurals (yinz, y'all, yous), either from various contractions or from adding a plural suffix to the singular pronoun.
2. The Modern Greek εσείς, the second-person plural. It exists because the original first-person plural and second-person plural (ἡμεῖς and ὑμεῖς) become homophones.

Comment: This really just echoes other answers.

Comment: ...and doesn't provide any references.

Answer (score -1):

Why-questions are often *too broad* because they have no unique answer if too many factors contribute to the problem.

The trivial answer in this one case is that people almost certainly have made up words, and do use various circumscriptions, to refer to a single third person of unidentified or non-binary gender, but these did not catch on. One reason is that the word was already in place ("they"). Also, circumscription works reasonably well ("a person", "a certain someone", more topical nouns; note that nouns can become pronouns on occasion, in other languages, and the grammatical distinction in English is fairly arbitrary, see also "someone", but "''the'' same one", from the same root in fact). In ternary logic, "don't care", or "X", may be considered one half of an unbalanced binary branching tree (which can be balanced by introducing another "don't care"  for free, but this should not distract us).

In particular, I doubt that "they" and "they" were the *same* word (singular and respectively plural). In fact, German *die* is very much related. The homonymy stems very likely from sound change affecting originally different exponents of a common root that is also observed in *the, there, that*, etc. The word *dia* that is mentioned in the question looks like it might well belong here, too. Very problematically, one might then ask *why* these changes have occurred, yet the common consensus in linguistics is still very often that they are arbitrary. Which brings us back to my initial premise, that the question is too broad; I might add, lacking in research, as I fully admit that my answer is lacking as well.

Comment: This is a CV-reason rather than an answer. I'd say this question and  'Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun {“his” vs. “her” vs. “their”}?' should be combined under the less open-to-opinion/'because English' title.

Comment: There is an explicit answer in the second paragraph. The first paragraph could be a CV-reason, that would be useless after the question was accepted. It is also an excuse for an incomplete answer. The accepted answer on the other hand doesn't even hint at the problem that I consider in need of an explanation, so I think I'm good, but thanks for the hint. I suppose the third paragraph lacks in substance, because I had better spent the time in research, so that the problem does not become apparent (are they *the same* word or much rather coincident?). It's missing a note on inflection especially

Comment: 'One reason is that the word was already in place'?

Comment: The note on German *die* in particular suggests that it may go back to a common ancestor, as 3rd person singular relative pronouns feminine *die* and regional *das* besides masculine 3rd person singular *das* and all gender 3rd person plural *die* suggest as much. There is in my humble opinion no reason to assume a priori that the plural and singular forms are identical, because the inflection endings still differ, which would have to agree in the pronouns and articles in the common ancestor language, unless I was severely mistaken.

Comment: [cont.] However, pronouns and articles are historically a huge mess, so it would lead too far astray for such a poor why-not question.

Comment: But Jon Hanna had 'Mostly, because they already have singular they' years ago. If that is your claimed explicit answer, it's a repeat.

Comment: He/she did not really say anything about the origin, except where they did they have not cited any sources. The entire answer as well as mine is pretty much blog spam if you want to look at it that way, but honest attempts at presenting an answer to the question, implying that the top answer is not satisfying, or somewhat uninteresting, or that they were simply hot for the bounty.

Answer (score -5):

Broadly because the great majority of English speakers don't notice that there's a question, and half the rest don't understand. They simply use what they grew up hearing, even if they never actually listened.

To get at "why", they'd first need to break the topic into at least two questions, strictly speaking separate:

```
Is "singular they" an accepted part of English?

How, when and why is "singular they" acceptable?
```

I suggest most Users are more than happy to answer "Yes (of course)" to the first and consign all discussion of "how" or "when" or "why" to  such a geeky, nerdy part of Academia, it could never enter their own, every-day speech, so why look further?

Those who do care generally recognise that little thought is needed to show most uses up as abuses, so why look further?

What remains prolly is purely academic again, so why look further?

Comment: Posts here are community-edited so that they can be improved. Randomly capitalizing nouns like *user* makes your post harder to understand, not easier. And you should not be using code markup here.