# Which pronoun do I use to refer a gender-neutral subject?

Tags: pronouns, gender-neutral

I want to say that "Feeding from a human doesn't mean killing **them**" (yes, vampire stuff), but I feel like the *them* I'm using isn't correct.

But I don't want to use he/she because a human can be either, and I don't want to use *it* because it sounds weird. What is the best option here?

Comment: Not your fault, but EL&U desperately need a list of the most commonly asked questions on the right-hand side. This will help visitors immediately find the answers they are looking for and save veteran users time in posting relavant links and close questions for being duplicates.

Comment: We resort to the singular *they* because of a lack of alternatives. We rephrase where possible to avoid the mess. "Feeding from doesn't mean killing a human."

Comment: The solution is easier than you think, change the singular "human" to the plural "Feeding from human**s** doesn't mean killing **them**" Although I have strong reserves about its phrasing/structure.

Comment: Related: **1** [Why use singular they? Why not make a new word to distinguish its meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/464606/44619), **2** [Why haven't we used “it” instead of “he or she”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/why-havent-we-used-it-instead-of-he-or-she), and **3** [Is it appropriate to refer to a person of unknown sex by “it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56567/is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-a-person-of-unknown-sex-by-it)

Answer (score 0):

Using "them" as a gender-neutral pronoun in this way is grammatically acceptable and is what a modern, native speaker would say.

Much has been [written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Acceptability_and_prescriptive_guidance) about the use of "them"as a replacement for the antiquated "him" as an [epicene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicenity). You could restructure to use the plural "humans" in line with traditional advice but it is progressively more acceptable to use the singular they (*them*) as you have.